# Foreign key reference with ON UPDATE CASCADE inside array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I've a natural primary key in table `A`.

In table `B`, I want to have an array of foreign key references to `A`.

Is it possible to specify `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on the elements of the array, such that when the value of a primary key in table A changes, arrays in `B` get modified.
Or should I just normalise the array out into a separate table?

Answer (score 2):

Normalizing this would allow you to use standard [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) in a foreign key constraint. That would be **much** faster, because the system can use plain indexes. That should give you **three** tables. Needs somewhat more disk space, but worth every bit:

- table a
- table b
- table a_b  -- to implement n:m relationship

See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
- [Can PostgreSQL array be optimized for join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156345/can-postgresql-array-be-optimized-for-join/38160897#38160897)

Else you will  have to write a trigger function to find and replace all references in B to values of master A.

Comment: Agreed- you definitely want to do it this way. You don't want to get in to messy, slow triggers. A little extra disk space saves you a lot of hassle and query time.

Comment: Hmmm, although I didn't mention it, I'm in the process of denormalising from an existing a_b table.  Because I've got compound/natural primary keys in a, the little extra disk space in this case more than doubles disk space usage, and is significant.

Comment: @EoghanM: In this case I would resort to surrogate primary keys. Add a serial column as primary (or unique) key.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to specify ON UPDATE CASCADE on the elements of the
>   array, such that when the value of a primary key in table A changes,
>   arrays in B get modified.

Only if

- both the referenced column and the referencing column are arrays of the same type, and
- the values have the same number of elements.

If you want to insert valid values for array elements in one table, and in another table store an array of those valid values, it won't work.

OTOH, this *does* work, but only in part.

```
create table a (
  str varchar[2] primary key
);

create table b (
  -- Room for two values from table a . . .
  str varchar[4] primary key references a (str) on update cascade
);

insert into a values 
('{''A'', ''B''}'),
('{''C'', ''D''}'),
('{''E'', ''F''}');

insert into b values 
('{''A'', ''B''}');

update a set str = '{''A'',''C''}'
where str = '{''A'',''B''}';

select * from b;
{'A','C'}
```

That much works. But if you try to store two arrays in table b, you'll get an error.

```
insert into b values
('{{"C", "D"}, {"E", "F"}}');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "b" violates foreign key constraint "b_str_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (str)=({{C,D},{E,F}}) is not present in table "a".
```

And, when you squint and tilt your head just right, that makes sense. In the relational model, the intersection of every row and column contains just one value. So you shouldn't be able to update half a value by `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.