# How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

I believe the title is self-explanatory. How do you create the table structure in  PostgreSQL to make a many-to-many relationship.

My example:

```
Product(name, price);
Bill(name, date, Products);
```

Comment: remove products from the bill table, create a new table called "bill_products" with two fields: one pointing at products, one pointing at bill. make those two fields this new table's primary key.

Comment: So bill_products(bill, products); ? And both of them PK?

Comment: yeah. they'd be individually an FK pointing at their respective tables, and together they'd be the PK for the new table.

Comment: So, bill_product(product references product.name, bill references bill.name , (product, bill) primary key) ?

Comment: They'd point to whateve the PK fields of the Product and Bill tables would be.

Comment: pivot table between the tables

Answer (score 446, accepted):

The SQL DDL (data definition language) statements could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  product_id serial PRIMARY KEY  -- implicit primary key constraint
, product    text NOT NULL
, price      numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE bill (
  bill_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, bill     text NOT NULL
, billdate date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);

CREATE TABLE bill_product (
  bill_id    int REFERENCES bill (bill_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, product_id int REFERENCES product (product_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
, amount     numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
, CONSTRAINT bill_product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (bill_id, product_id)  -- explicit pk
);
```

I made a few adjustments:

- The **n:m relationship** is normally implemented by a separate table - `bill_product` in this case.
- I added [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) columns as **surrogate primary keys**. In Postgres 10 or later consider an [`IDENTITY` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) instead. See:

  - [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)
  - [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)
  - https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns/

  I highly recommend that, because the name of a product is hardly unique (not a good "natural key"). Also, enforcing uniqueness and referencing the column in foreign keys is typically cheaper with a 4-byte `integer` (or even an 8-byte `bigint`) than with a string stored as `text` or `varchar`.
- Don't use names of basic data types like `date` as **identifiers**. While this is possible, it is bad style and leads to confusing errors and error messages. Use [legal, lower case, unquoted identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Never use [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and avoid double-quoted mixed case identifiers if you can.
- "name" is not a good name. I renamed the column of the table `product` to be `product` (or `product_name` or similar). That is a better **naming convention**. Otherwise, when you join a couple of tables in a query - which you do *a lot* in a relational database - you end up with multiple columns named "name" and have to use column aliases to sort out the mess. That's not helpful. Another widespread anti-pattern would be just "id" as column name.
  I am not sure what the name of a `bill` would be. `bill_id` will probably suffice in this case.
- `price` is of **data type** `numeric` to store fractional numbers *precisely as entered* (arbitrary precision type instead of floating point type). If you deal with whole numbers exclusively, make that `integer`. For example, you could save *prices as Cents*.
- The `amount` (`"Products"` in your question) goes into the linking table `bill_product` and is of type `numeric` as well. Again, `integer` if you deal with whole numbers exclusively.
- You see the **foreign keys** in `bill_product`? I created both to cascade changes: `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. If a `product_id` or `bill_id` should change, the change is cascaded to all depending entries in `bill_product` and nothing breaks. Those are just references without significance of their own.
  I also used `ON DELETE CASCADE` for `bill_id`: If a bill gets deleted, its details die with it.
  Not so for products: You don't want to delete a product that's used in a bill. Postgres will throw an error if you attempt this. You would add another column to `product` to mark obsolete rows ("soft-delete") instead.
- All columns in this basic example end up to be **`NOT NULL`**, so `NULL` values are not allowed. (Yes, *all* columns - primary key columns are defined `UNIQUE NOT NULL` automatically.) That's because `NULL` values wouldn't make sense in any of the columns. It makes a beginner's life easier. But you won't get away so easily, you need to understand [`NULL` handling](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) anyway. Additional columns might allow `NULL` values, functions and joins can introduce `NULL` values in queries etc.
- Read the chapter on [`CREATE TABLE` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).
- Primary keys are implemented with a unique **index** on the key columns, that makes queries with conditions on the PK column(s) fast. However, the sequence of key columns is relevant in multicolumn keys. Since the PK on `bill_product` is on `(bill_id, product_id)` in my example, you may want to add another index on just `product_id` or `(product_id, bill_id)` if you have queries looking for a given `product_id` and no `bill_id`. See:

  - [PostgreSQL composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352056/postgresql-composite-primary-key/11352543#11352543)
  - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)
  - [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7484/3684)
- Read the [chapter on indexes in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html).

Comment: How can I create an index for the mapping table `bill_product`? Normally it should looks like: `CREATE INDEX idx_bill_product_id ON booked_rates(bill_id, product_id)`. Is this right?

Comment: @codyLine: This index  is created automatically by the PK.