# PostgreSQL composite primary key

Tags: postgresql, indexing, composite-primary-key

In MySQL, when I create a composite primary key, say with columns `X, Y, Z`, then all three columns become indexes automatically. Does the same happen for Postgres?

Comment: Do you mean MySQL creates **three** *indexes*? Sounds awfully strange

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you create a composite primary key, on `(x, y, z)`, PostgreSQL implements this with the help of one `UNIQUE` multi-column btree index on `(x, y, z)`. In addition, all three columns are `NOT NULL` (implicitly), which is the main difference between a `PRIMARY KEY` and a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Besides obvious restrictions on your data, the [multi-column index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) also has a somewhat different effect on the performance of queries than three individual indexes on `x`, `y` and `z`.

Related discussion on dba.SE:

- [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684)

With examples, benchmarks, discussion and outlook on the new feature of [*index-only scans* in Postgres 9.2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#Index-only_scans).

In particular, a primary key on `(x, y, z)` will speed up queries with conditions on `x`, `(x,y)` or `(x,y,z)` optimally. It will also help with queries on `y`, `z`, `(y,z)` or `(x,z)` but to a far lesser extent.

If you need to speed up queries on the latter combinations, you may want to change the order of column in your PK constraint and/or create one or more additional indexes. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Comment: So if I add UNIQUE  on multiple columns say, `UNIQUE(a,c)`, then it will create a unique index in the background for `(a,c)` as a whole but will it also create indexes for `a` and `c` separately? because later I may need to search only on column `c` or column `a`. Please advice

Comment: @AlwaysSunny: No, only *one* multicolumn index on `(a,c)` is created. But that index can still be used (close to optimally) for searches on `(a)` and (much less efficiently) for searches on `(c)`. Consider an additional index on `(c)` or `(c,a)`. But read the two linked answer above, first.

Answer (score 4):

No, you get one index for the three-column primary key.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-unique.html):

> PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table. The index covers the columns that make up the primary key or unique constraint (a multicolumn index, if appropriate), and is the mechanism that enforces the constraint.

Comment: I think the question was whether each column gets its own index.

Comment: Agree. The question is not if 1 multicolumn index is automatically created but well if 3 single column indexes are created. And the answer is no. Your answer is still relevant as it provides supplementary informations, after being edited of course. In fact, the answer of @dondi-michael-stroma is more relevant than the one which has been chosen by the original requester.