# Query with UNION or OR?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table `friend` used to store the relationship between two user.

For example: `(1,2)` means user1 and user2 are friends. `(2,1)` means the same, but there we won't store that, making `uid1 < uid2` manually:

```
CREATE TABLE public.friend (
  uid1 INTEGER,
  uid2 INTEGER
);
CREATE INDEX index_uid1 ON friend USING BTREE (uid1);
CREATE INDEX index_uid2 ON friend USING BTREE (uid2);
```

To find the friends of `uid=2`, I can use:

Sql1:

```
select * from friend where uid1=2
union
select * from friend where uid2=2;
```

Sql2:

```
select * from friend uid1=2 or uid2=2
```

What I get is that *sql2* is better than *sql1* in performance.

But *sql1* is recommended. Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you say that "SQL1 is recommended"?  Why do you say that "SQL2 is beter in performance"?

Comment: This example is from an article which says SQL1 is better

Comment: Then show us the article.  We can't comment on why an article says something without reading the article.

Comment: I describe simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a table `friend` used to store the relationship between two
>   user.
>
> For example: `(1,2)` means user1 and user2 are friends. `(2,1)` means
>   the same, but there we won't store that, making `uid1 < uid2`
>   manually:

Typically, you would implement that with have a [`PRIMARY KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) on `(udi1, uid2)` and a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) enforcing `uid1 < uid2`.

```
CREATE TABLE public.friend (
   uid1 integer
 , uid2 integer
 , PRIMARY KEY (uid1, uid2)
 , CONSTRAINT uid2_gt_uid1 CHECK (uid1 < uid2)
);

CREATE INDEX index_uid2 ON friend USING BTREE (uid2);
```

You don't need the other index, it's covered by the index of the PK;

```
CREATE INDEX index_uid1 ON friend USING BTREE (uid1);
```

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)
- [PostgreSQL composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352056/postgresql-composite-primary-key/11352543#11352543)

Then there cannot be duplicates (including switched duplicates) and nobody can be friend with him/her self either, and your query can simply be:

```
SELECT * FROM friend WHERE 2 IN (uid1, uid2);
```

... which is short for:

```
SELECT * FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 2 OR uid2 = 2;
```

And the `UNION` variant is now logically identical:

```
SELECT * FROM friend WHERE uid1=2
UNION
SELECT * FROM friend WHERE uid2=2;
```

But you would `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION` as there are no duplicates to begin with and `UNION ALL` is cheaper. But still slightly more expensive than the single `SELECT` above.

#### Duplicates?

There are *three* *possible* sources of duplicates in the `UNION ALL` query:

1. **Duplicate rows** in the underlying table (ruled out by the PK).
2. **Rows fetched multiple times** by more than one `SELECT` branch.
3. In your particular case: ***logical*** duplicates with switched IDs (ruled out by the `CHECK` constraint).

Once you understand this, you also understand the implications of the different query techniques. With the suggest setup, only `2.` remains as possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

They are not technically the same, the union operator will remove duplicates, while the 2nd example does not.

Answer (score 1):

`union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  Perhaps the most efficient method for the query is:

```
select f.* from friend f where uid1 = 2
union all
select f.* from friend f where uid2 = 2 and uid1 <> 2;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of indexes on `f(uid1)` and `f(uid2)`.  Your second version is probably doing a full table scan.