# What is the best way to create index and unique constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database-design

What is the best way to create an index as well as unique constraint on a schema like below?

Most of my queries will filter based on `date` column. If I create single column index on `date` and a unique constraint including both (date and key), I end up creating two indices as unique constraint also creates an index.

Is there a better way around this?

| date | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-12-2021 | a | 3 |
| 12-12-2021 | b | 4 |
| 12-13-2021 | a | 3 |
| 12-13-2021 | b | 4 |

Comment: by creating a primary key on (date,key) will get you an index as well as uniqueness enforced. Queries thta use just date field filter would most likely be using a range scan, as its on the leading edge(first_column) of the index

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

> Most of my queries will filter based on date column.

That's not enough information. For *equality* filters, a `PRIMARY KEY` on `(date, key)` (with `date` as *leading* column!) will typically do just fine:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  date  date
, key   text
, value int
, PRIMARY KEY (date, key)
);
```

Because ... see:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)
- [PostgreSQL composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352056/postgresql-composite-primary-key/11352543#11352543)
- [Why can I create a table with PRIMARY KEY on a nullable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006374/why-can-i-create-a-table-with-primary-key-on-a-nullable-column/20006502#20006502)
- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

This also covers *range* filters on `date`, but it's less than ideal when combined with an equality filter on `key`, because ... see:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684)

If your table is as simple as your example suggests and you typically include `value` in the `SELECT` list, consider a **covering index** (requires Postgres 11 or later) to get index-only scans:

```sql
...
, PRIMARY KEY (date, key) INCLUDE (value)
```

See:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207938/3684)