# Postgres Check if One to many relationship has all values in another relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a table which contains all the Reports

```
   report_id   | Name 
---------------+-------------
      1        | Sales Q3
      2        | Sales Q2
```

I have a relation table which contains one to many relations about the report with dept

```
  report_id   |  dept_id  
-----------------+---------------
      1       | 4
      1       | 5
      2       | 4
```

Relation Table signifies report(1) contains data about dept(4 & 5)
and report(2) contains data about dept(4)

I have another table which specifies relation between users and departments.

```
  user_id     |  dept_id  
-----------------+---------------
      1       | 4
      1       | 5
      2       | 4
      3       | 5
```

Users table also signifies the relation between user and dept.

I need to fetch all set of reports for a particular user only if the user has relation to all the department in that particular report.

For example

User(1)  has access to dept(4,5) so query should return both report(1,2)

User(2)  has access to dept(4) so query should return only report(2) and should not return report(1) as it has relation with dept(5)

User(3)  has access to dept(5) so query should not return any reports as both the report has relation with dept(4)

A query like

```
Select * from reports inner join relation on relation.report_id = reports.report_id ( some condition to satisfy all rows of relations.dept_id are present in users.dept_id table ) where users.user_id = 1
```

Given the above use case, Are these tables right way to maintain the relationship between reports,department and users?

Edit:

Added Schema definitions

Postgres Version 9.5

```
CREATE TABLE reports (
    report_id integer NOT NULL,
    report_name varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE relation (
    report_id integer NOT NULL,
    dept_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    dept_id integer NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO reports VALUES(1, 'Sales Q3'),(2, 'Sales Q2');
INSERT INTO relation VALUES(1, 4),(1, 5),(2,4);
INSERT INTO users VALUES(1, 4),(1, 5),(2,4),(3,5);
```

Comment: Can you please give proper table definitions? `CREATE TABLE` statements. Ideally a fiddle with sample data. And always your version of Postgres. Also "relation" is not a useful table name. There are any number of "relations" in a relational DB.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Added table definitions in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used arrays to achieve the case.

Created an array of dept_id the users have access to and converted the dept_id in report to arrays.

Checked if user dept array is completely present in reports dept array.

```
select reports.report_name,rel.report_id,rel.dept_list from reports 
inner join 
(select report_id,count(*) as total,array_agg(dept_id) as dept_list 
from relation group by report_id) 
rel on rel.report_id=reports.report_id and 
rel.dept_list <@ (select array_agg(dept_id) as user_dept_list from users where user_id=1 group by user_id);
```

Comment: Consider the optimized version I added to my answer - together with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

We can try a join approach with the help of `COUNT()` used as a window function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rels.user_id, rpt.report_id, rpt.Name,
           COUNT(rel.dept_id) OVER (PARTITION BY rels.user_id) rpt_cnt,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rels.user_id) total_cnt
    FROM relations rels
    LEFT JOIN relation rel ON rel.dept_id = rels.dept_id
    INNER JOIN reports rpt ON rpt.report_id = rel.report_id
)

SELECT user_id, report_id, Name
FROM cte
WHERE rpt_cnt = total_cnt
ORDER BY user_id, report_id;
```

The idea in the above is that we try to find for each user's department, a matching report.  We return all of a given user's reports in the case where all departments match to a report.

Answer (score 0):

*"Find reports for any department the given user is part of, and not released for any department the user is not."*

```sql
WITH usr AS (SELECT dept_id FROM users WHERE user_id = 1)
SELECT rep.report_name, rel.*
FROM   reports rep
JOIN  (
   SELECT report_id, array_agg(dept_id) AS dept_list 
   FROM   usr
   JOIN   relation rel USING (dept_id)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) rel  USING (report_id)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM relation rel1
   WHERE  rel1.report_id = rel.report_id
   AND    rel1.dept_id NOT IN (TABLE usr)
   );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ws30EfMl)

Based on a couple of assumptions, the question did not disclose. Like: all involved columns are defined `NOT NULL`.

For optimal performance, have an **index** on `relation(dept_id, report_id)` **and** one on `relation(report_id, dept_id)` (with the other column first). One of both could be the PK, the other one an additional plain index. See indexes in my fiddle! And see:

- [PostgreSQL composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352056/postgresql-composite-primary-key/11352543#11352543)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)
- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

You later posted an answer with a similar query - which can be optimized:

```sql
SELECT rep.report_name, rel.*
FROM   reports rep
JOIN  (
   SELECT report_id, array_agg(dept_id) AS dept_list
   FROM   relation
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) rel USING (report_id)
WHERE  rel.dept_list <@ ARRAY(SELECT dept_id FROM users WHERE user_id = 1)
ORDER  BY rep.report_id;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ws30EfMl)

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

My first query should perform better with big tables because it excludes most irrelevant reports early, while your query has to process *all* reports.