# Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, ddl

I know that PostgreSQL tables that use a `SERIAL` primary key end up with an implicit index, sequence and constraint being created by PostgreSQL. The question is how to rename these implicit objects when the table is renamed. Below is my attempt at figuring this out with specific questions at the end.

Given a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    pkey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value INTEGER
);
```

Postgres outputs:

> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "foo_pkey_seq" for serial column "foo.pkey"
>   NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "foo_pkey" for table "foo"
>   Query returned successfully with no result in 52 ms.

pgAdmin III SQL pane shows the following DDL script for the table (decluttered):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  pkey serial NOT NULL,
  value integer,
  CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pkey )
);
ALTER TABLE foo OWNER TO postgres;
```

**Now rename the table:**

```
ALTER table foo RENAME TO bar;
```

> Query returned successfully with no result in 17 ms.

pgAdmin III:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (
  pkey integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('foo_pkey_seq'::regclass),
  value integer,
  CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pkey )
);
ALTER TABLE bar OWNER TO postgres;
```

Note the extra  **`DEFAULT nextval('foo_pkey_seq'::regclass),`** this means that renaming the table does not rename the sequence for the primary keys but now we have this explicit `nextval()`.

**Now rename the sequence:**

I want to keep the database naming consistent so I tried:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE foo_pkey_seq RENAME TO bar_pkey_seq;
```

> Query returned successfully with no result in 17 ms.

pgAdmin III:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (
  pkey serial NOT NULL,
  value integer,
  CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pkey )
);
ALTER TABLE bar OWNER TO postgres;
```

The **`DEFAULT nextval('foo_pkey_seq'::regclass),`** is gone.

#### QUESTIONS

1. Why did the `DEFAULT nextval('foo_pkey_seq'::regclass)` statement appear and disappear?
2. Is there a way to rename the table and have the primary key sequence renamed at the same time?
3. Is it safe to rename the table then sequence while clients are connected to the database, are there any concurrency issues?
4. How does postgres know which sequence to use? Is there a database trigger being used internally? Is there anything else to rename other than the table and the sequence?
5. What about the implicit index created by a primary key? Should that be renamed? If so, how can that be done?
6. What about the constraint name above? It is still `foo_pkey`. How is a constraint renamed?

Comment: My guess would be that naming a sequence `<<tablename>>_pkey_seq` has magical syntactical significance, and that Postgres knows to use a so-named sequence as a table's primary key sequence and to omit explicitly listing it as the default value of a table's primary key column. I don't actually know this or have any evidence for it, though. Will investigate further after work if this question doesn't have an answer by then.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`serial` is not an actual data type. [The manual states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> The data types `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are not true types,
>   but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns

The pseudo data type is resolved doing all of this:

- create a sequence named `tablename_colname_seq`
- create the column with type `integer` (or `int2` / `int8` respectively for `smallserial` / `bigserial`)
- make the column `NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')`
- make the column own the sequence, so that it gets dropped with it automatically

The system does *not* know whether you did all this by hand or by way of the pseudo data type `serial`. pgAdmin checks on the listed features and if all are met, the reverse engineered DDL script is simplified with the matching `serial` type. If one of the features is not met, this simplification does not take place. That is something pgAdmin does. For the underlying catalog tables it's all the same. There is no `serial` type as such.

There is no way to automatically rename owned sequences. You can run:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE ... RENAME TO ...
```

like you did. The system itself doesn't care about the *name*. The column `DEFAULT` stores an [`OID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) (`'foo_pkey_seq'::regclass`), you can change the name of the sequence without breaking that - the OID stays the same. The same goes for foreign keys and similar references inside the database.

The implicit index for the primary key is bound to the name of the PK constraint, which will *not* change if you change the name of the table. [In Postgres 9.2 or later you can use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

```
ALTER TABLE ... RENAME CONSTRAINT ..
```

to rectify that, too.

There can also be indexes named in reference to the table name. [Similar procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterindex.html):

```
ALTER INDEX .. RENAME TO  ..
```

You can have all kinds of informal references to the table name. The system cannot forcibly rename objects that can be named anything you like. And it doesn't care.

Of course you don't want to invalidate SQL code that references those names. Obviously, you don't want to change names while application logic references them. Normally this wouldn't be a problem for names of indexes, sequences or constraints, since those are not normally referenced by name.

Postgres also acquires a lock on objects before renaming them. So if there are **concurrent transaction** open that have any kind of lock on objects in question, your `RENAME` operation is stalled until those transactions commit or roll back.

#### System catalogs and OIDs

The database schema is stored in tables of the system catalog in the system schema `pg_catalog`. [All details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) If you don't know exactly what you are doing, **you shouldn't be messing with those tables at all**. One false move and you can break your database. [Use the DDL commands Postgres provides.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html)

For some of the most important tables Postgres provides [object identifier types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) and type casts to get the name for the OID and vice versa quickly. Like:

```
SELECT 'foo_pkey_seq'::regclass
```

If the schema name is in the `search_path` and the table name is unique, that gives you the same as:

```
SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'foo_pkey_seq';
```

The primary key of most catalog tables is `oid` and internally, most references use OIDs.

Comment: "ALTER TABLE ... RENAME CONSTRAINT .." requires PostgreSQL 9.2+ Maybe that's helpful for I've just debugged for an hour on this :-P Great answer!