# Autoincrementing serial data type

Tags: postgresql, sequence, auto-increment, pgadmin

I have searched a lot related concerning the `serial` data type.
I had defined a table with one column as `serial`. How do I set the start value for this column using pgAdmin?

Answer (score 3):

Note that `serial` is a pseudo type. Details here:
[Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)
[Safely and cleanly rename tables that use serial primary key columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)

Values come from an attached [**sequence**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html). To start with a certain value, change the sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tbl_tbl_id_seq START 123;
```

In pgAdmin, select the **sequence** in the object browser, open the properties and set the current value:

[image: sequence properties]

By default, the next value retrieved will be the one *after* the value you set.