# PostgreSQL sequence connects to columns

Tags: postgresql, sequence, psql

So im working on a database at the moment, and i can see there are loads of sequences. I was wondering how sequences link up to their corresponding column in order to increment the value.

for example if i create a new table with a column names ID how would i apply a sequence to that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, sequences are created implicitly. With a `serial` column or (alternatively) with an `IDENTITY` column in Postgres 10 or later. Details:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Sequences are separate objects internally and can be "owned" by a column, which happens automatically for the above examples. (But you can also have free-standing sequences.) They are incremented with the dedicated function `nextval()` that is used for the column default of above columns automatically. More [sequence manipulation functions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html).

Details:

- [Safely and cleanly rename tables that use serial primary key columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)

Or you can use [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) to manipulate various properties.

**Privileges** on sequences have to be changed explicitly for `serial` columns, while that happens implicitly for the newer `IDENTITY` columns.