# Postgres Multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

This im hoping is a simple one. but i have a table that is called product. One column is called Parts. Basically i need to store multiple arrays in there, with each array holding a reference to a part ID and the quantity required. I dont really know the best way to set it up. There could be up to about 25 parts for one product yet another have 3.

Any advice would be a great help!

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Why don't you want to setup a link table, `product_part`?

Comment: Don't do it. Set it up relational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems best to [setup a Many-to-Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql) with another table and link to that. If you insist on storing the array as a string - [use JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php), you can always [encode your array(s) to JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and store it as such, then when you pull it out, you merely [decode from JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) back to array.

Comment: how will i store the foreign id and quantity together?

as one product may have a different quantity requirement of a part to another product so i cant set quantity in the foreign table

Comment: In a cross reference table, just keep |product_id|part_id|quantity| The link I provided demonstrates this with the bill_product table.