# Need cleaner update method in PostgreSQL 9.1.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, triggers

Using PostgreSQL 9.1.3 I have a `points` table like so (What's the right way to show tables here??)

```
| Column |     Type          |            Table Modifiers                          | Storage
|--------|-------------------|-----------------------------------------------------|----------|
| id     | integer           | not null default nextval('points_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |
| name   | character varying | not null                                            | extended |
| abbrev | character varying | not null                                            | extended |
| amount | real              | not null                                            | plain    |
```

In another table, `orders` I have a bunch of columns where the name of the column exists in the `points` table via the abbrev column, as well as a `total_points` column

```
| Column       | Type   | Table Modifiers    |
|--------------|--------|--------------------|
| ud           | real   | not null default 0 |
| sw           | real   | not null default 0 |
| prrv         | real   | not null default 0 |
| total_points | real   | default 0          |
```

So in `orders` I have the `sw` column, and in `points` I'll now have an `amount` that realtes to the column where `abbrev` = sw

I have about 15 columns like that in the `points` table, and now I want to set a trigger so that when I create/update an entry in the `points` table, I calculate a total score.  Basically with just those three shown I could do it long-hand like this:

```sql
UPDATE points
SET total_points =
    ud * (SELECT amount FROM points WHERE abbrev = 'ud') +
    sw * (SELECT amount FROM points WHERE abbrev = 'sw') +
    prrv * (SELECT amount FROM points WHERE abbrev = 'prrv')  
WHERE ....
```

But that's just plain ugly and repetative, and like I said there are really 15 of them (right now...).  I'm hoping there's a more sophisticated way to handle this.

In general each of those silly names on the `orders` table represents a type of work associated with the order, and each of those types has a 'cost' to it, which is stores in the `points` table.  I'm not married to this structure if there's a cleaner setup.

Comment: If someone is going to suggest a different structure, I should note that for every order I'll want to know the value of each of those items, even if it's a 0

Comment: The best way to show the table definition is what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. Or the complete `CREATE` script (which you can copy from pgAdmin in the object browser).

Comment: You don't want `UPDATE points`, you want `UPDATE orders` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Serialize" the costs for orders:

```
CREATE TABLE order_cost (
   order_cost_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , order_id      int NOT NULL REFERENCES order
 , cost_type_id  int NOT NULL REFERENCES points
 , cost          int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  -- in Cent
);
```

For a single row:

```
UPDATE orders o
SET    total_points = COALESCE((
   SELECT sum(oc.cost * p.amount) AS order_cost
   FROM   order_cost oc
   JOIN   points p ON oc.cost_type_id = p.id
   WHERE  oc.order_id = o.order_id
   ), 0);
WHERE  o.order_id =  $<order_id>   -- your order_id here ...
```

**Never** use the lossy type `real` for currency data. Use exact types like `money`, `numeric` or just `integer` - where integer is supposed to store the amount in Cent.

More advice in this closely related example:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: So if I do this you're suggesting I remove the other columns from the orders table, right?  This would simply replace that?  I've been trying to make much better posts for you too :)

Comment: I suggest a table `orders` (plural because order is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html); other than that I always use single terms for tables where one row hold a single entity.) with general details for the order and another table `order_cost` with 0-n cost factors for the order.