# Query to count items across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

```
ID | fish1 | fish2 | fish3 |
1  | shark | dolfy | whale |
2  | tuna  | shark | dolfy |
3  | dolfy | shark | tuna  |
4  | dolfy | tuna  | shark |
```

and the result of he query is:

```
fish  | count |
shark | 4     |
tuna  | 3     |
dolfy | 4     |
whale | 1     |
```

Can someone give me a proper query for this.

Comment: Whales not being fish is the least of what seems amiss here. Looks like a misguided **many-to-many** implementation, with 3 tables at the core: `tbl`, `fish` and `tbl_fish` connecting the first two. The query would be trivial, then. Example implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225. You could add an attribute `fish_type enum` that can be one of `(fish1, fish2, fish3)` and add a unique or primary constraint over `(tbl_id, fish_id, fish_type)` to limit to 3 fish per entry in `tbl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a normalized view on your de-normalized table:

```
select fish, 
       count(*)
from (
  select fish1 as fish from the_table
  union all
  select fish2 from the_table
  union all
  select fish3 from the table
) t
group by fish
```

In general it's a bad idea to store your data like that (numbered columns very often indicate a bad design).

You should rather think about a proper one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
select fish, count (id)
from
(
SELECT fish1 as fish, id from my_table
union all
SELECT fish2 as fish, id from my_table
union all
SELECT fish3 as fish, id from my_table
) A
group by fish
```

Comment: Which link are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

Another of doing it

```
select 'shark' as fish, count(case when fish1='shark' then 1 end)+count(case when fish2='shark' then 1 end)+
        count(case when fish3='shark' then 1 end) count from yourtable
union all
select 'tuna', count(case when fish1='tuna' then 1 end)+count(case when fish2='tuna' then 1 end)+
        count(case when fish3='tuna' then 1 end) from yourtable
union all
select 'dolfy', count(case when fish1='dolfy' then 1 end)+count(case when fish2='dolfy' then 1 end)+
        count(case when fish3='dolfy' then 1 end) from yourtable
union all
select 'whale',count(case when fish1='whale' then 1 end)+count(case when fish2='whale' then 1 end)+
        count(case when fish3='whale' then 1 end) from yourtable
```

Comment: This has the huge disadvantage that you need to adjust the query each time you add a new fish type.