# JOIN 3 tables (or cross join?) and output 2 times users.name value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to join 3 tables - users, posts and comments to get value like post title, post author, comment title, comment author.

```
users (id, name)
posts (id, content, user_id)
comments (content, user_id, post_id)
```

Right now I have query:

```
SELECT posts.id AS POST_ID, posts.content AS Post, posts.user_id AS PostAuthorID,
users.name AS PostAuthorName,
comments.content AS comment, comments.user_id AS CommentsAuthorID
FROM posts
JOIN users on users.id = posts.user_id
JOIN comments ON users.id = comments.post_id;
```

My question is how to get author's name of each comment and how get the author of the post? Right now by doing `JOIN users on users.id = posts.user_id` I have post author but how to deal with comment author name? When I'm trying to add another condition to last join - `JOIN comments ON users.id = comments.post_id AND users.id = comments.user_id` I receive table with posts and comments created by the same user. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you meant:

```
ON posts.id = comments.post_id;
```

where your query currently says:

```
ON users.id = comments.post_id;
```

Then just join to `users` twice:

```
SELECT p.id AS post_id, p.content AS post, p.user_id AS post_author_id
     , pu.name AS post_author_name
     , c.content AS comment, c.user_id AS comment_author_id
     , cu.name AS comment_author_name
FROM posts    p
JOIN users    pu ON pu.id = p.user_id
JOIN comments c  ON c.post_id = p.id
JOIN users    cu ON cu.id = c.user_id;
```

Returns multiple rows for posts with multiple comments. One per comment. Returns *nothing* for posts without comments. To include posts without comments (or if any ID column can be NULL) use `LEFT JOIN` instead ...

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Thank you so much! one question - should I replace every `JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN` or only when I'm joining posts with users so `JOIN users    pu ON pu.id = p.user_id` ?

Comment: Simplified: whenever there might be no rows qualifying to the right of the join and you still want to keep the rows to the left, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. You have to either use `LEFT JOIN` as well for additional relations to the right (joining to left-joined relations), or use parentheses. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31486181/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28686060/939860

Comment: Superb explanation, I will use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. Maybe one additional question, if I wanna have total number of comments for each post where I should insert `COUNT` ? because when I'm trying to do it in a select i.e. `c.user_id, COUNT(*) AS total_comments I've `got syntax error at or near "("`

Comment: @wichru: We've already stretched *comments* here. Please ask your new question as *question*. You can always link to this one for context if that helps.

Comment: Nah, they gonna lynch me. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

```html
user (user_id, name)
post (post_id, user_id, descrition)
comment (cm_id, post_id, content)
you join  user with post by user_id and post with comment by post_id
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clearly - I edited my first post. So I wanna have table row called CommentName with name of each comment author name (I have user_id in comments table). Unfortunately your solution doesn't change anything because still I have comments just with user_id not with name.

Comment: Try to do : select x1.post_id, name, content, coment from 
(
select a.id , name, content, b.id post_id  from users a, posts b
where a.id =b.user_id 
)x1,


(
select a.id , content coment, b.id post_id  from users a, comments b
where a.id =b.user_id 
)x2 
where x1.user_id =x2.user_id
and x1.post_id =x2.post_id;

Answer (score 0):

```
Select comments.user_id AS CommentsAuthorID
Where posts.id = x
From (posts left join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id
```

If you just need the comments.user_id make a join with the posts and the comments.

When you want comments.users.name the query would be:

```
Select comments.user_id AS CommentsAuthorID comments.users_name AS UserName 
Where posts.id = x
From (posts left join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id
```

Comment: I have comments.user_id right now. Based on that id I wanna have something like `comments.users.name`. But in one query I wanna have post author so `posts.users.name`.

Comment: in the query above you just have to add these in the select clause.