# Extract XML file stored in a postgresql table

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have a XML file stored in postgresql table which contains array attribute type contains values such as

```
<Type>
      <V Idx="1">Cat</V>
      <V Idx="2">Mouse</V>
      <V Idx="3">Tree</V>
   </Type>
```

and I would like to extract the Idx value of "Cat" using postgresql query.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550813/storing-xml-into-postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xpath()` to use an XPath expression extracting parts of XML. It'll return an array of the matches, so you need to select the desired index if you want a scalar.

To get the `Idx` attribute of the first `/Type/V` that has a text of `Cat` you could use:

```
SELECT (xpath('(/Type/V[text()="Cat"]/@Idx)[1]', nmuloc))[1] idx
       FROM elbat;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=c7a85988e2a7238cec36735c6e866545)

Comment: It is working in but if xml header comes with url's it is not working. Can you please help me in that. For example : <sample-test-data-history xmlns="http://www.dmotorworks.com/sample-test-data-history">
  <payPaymentCode>
    <V Idx="1">CASH</V>
  </payPaymentCode>
  <StatusCode>C98</StatusCode>
  <Type>
      <V Idx="1">Cat</V>
      <V Idx="2">Mouse</V>
      <V Idx="3">Tree</V>
   </Type>
  <totMiscCost>
    <V Idx="1">100.00</V>
    <V Idx="2">150.00</V>
    <V Idx="3">200.00</V>
  </totMiscCost>
 
</sample-test-data-history>

Comment: From this xml i need to get the idx value of the array for which the text is "cat" and based on that Idx value I need to get totMiscCost from the next array attribute with the same Idx value