# Query returning too many results

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

SQL query that returns expected 29 results for `a.id = 366`

```
    select a.name, c.name, MAX(B.date), MAX(b.renew_date) as MAXDATE
    from boson_course c
    inner join boson_coursedetail b on (c.id = b.course_id)
    inner join boson_coursedetail_attendance d on (d.coursedetail_id = b.id)
    inner join boson_employee a on (a.id = d.employee_id)
    where a.id = 366
    GROUP BY a.name, c.name
    order by MAX(b.renew_date), MAX(b.date) desc;
```

SQL code below that returns 34 results, multiple results where two different Provides supplied the same course. I know these extra results are because I added `e.name` to the list to be returned. But all that is needed is the 29 entries with the latest date and Providers names.

```
    select a.name, c.name, e.name, MAX(B.date), MAX(b.renew_date) as MAXDATE
    from boson_course c
    inner join boson_coursedetail b on (c.id = b.course_id)
    inner join boson_coursedetail_attendance d on (d.coursedetail_id = b.id)
    inner join boson_employee a on (a.id = d.employee_id)
    inner join boson_provider e on b.provider_id = e.id
    where a.id = 366
    GROUP BY a.name, c.name, e.name
    order by MAX(b.renew_date), MAX(b.date) desc;
```

Can anyone rework this code to return a single DISTINCT Provider name with the `MAX(renew_date)` for each course.

Comment: I'm confused since adding the provider on the id for the provider, assuming boson_provider.id is the primary key, shouldn't have added any new rows.  Is there any chance there are two providers with the same id in the boson_provider table?

Comment: Do you want the `date` from the row with the `MAX(renew_date)` or `max(date)`, which may be different. As always, your  version of Postgres should be in the question.

Comment: Postgres version 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns exactly ***one*** row per distinct combination of `(a.name, c.name)`:
The one with the latest `renew_date`.
Among these, the one with the latest `date` (may differ from global `max(date)`!).
Among these, the one with the alphabetically first `e.name`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.name, c.name)
       a.name AS a_name, c.name AS c_name, e.name AS e_name
     , b.renew_date, b.date
FROM   boson_course       c
JOIN   boson_coursedetail b on c.id = b.course_id
JOIN   boson_coursedetail_attendance d on d.coursedetail_id = b.id
JOIN   boson_employee     a on a.id = d.employee_id
JOIN   boson_provider     e on b.provider_id = e.id
WHERE  a.id = 366
ORDER  BY a.name, c.name
     , b.renew_date DESC NULLS LAST
     , b.date DESC NULLS LAST
     , e.name;
```

The result is sorted by `a_name`, `c_name` first. If you need your **original sort order**, wrap this in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (<query from above>) sub
ORDER  BY renew_date DESC NULLS LAST
        , date DESC NULLS LAST
        , a_name, c_name, e_name;
```

Explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Why `DESC NULL LAST`?

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Aside: Don't use basic type names like `date` ad column names. Also, `name` is hardly ever a good name. As you can see, we have to use aliases to make this query useful. Some general advice on naming conventions:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: Many thanks Erwin for the update, works like a dream.  And thank you for the extra insightful/educational links.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (a.name, c.name, e.name), a.name, c.name, e.name,
       B.date, b.renew_date as MAXDATE
from boson_course c
inner join boson_coursedetail b on (c.id = b.course_id)
inner join boson_coursedetail_attendance d on (d.coursedetail_id = b.id)
inner join boson_employee a on (a.id = d.employee_id)
inner join boson_provider e on b.provider_id = e.id
where a.id = 366
ORDER BY a.name, c.name, e.name, B.date desc
order by MAX(b.renew_date), MAX(b.date) desc;
```