# Database Design Advice for a Social Network App Needed

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection, relational-database, database-schema

I am very new into backend stuffs like databases. That being said, I lack the database design knowledge.

I am wondering how and what is the best design for my scenario.

I am creating a social network app where the **users can create groups** and **join other groups**. Those **groups** have **places** in it. **Those places** are **created by** the **User in the group**

> 1. **User**
> 2. **Group**
> 3. **Place**

Rules:

> 1. One **User** can create and join many **Groups**
> 2. One **Group** can contain many **Users**
> 3. One **Group** can have many **Places**
> 4. Each **Group** have an admin **User**

I currently have 3 separate tables

**1. USER TABLE**

> ID, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD, PROFILE PICTURE

**2. GROUP TABLE**

> ID, NAME

**3. PLACE TABLE**

> ID, NAME, COORDINATE, RADIUS

I am extremely confused in designing the proper database for it it.

Question:

1. How should I design the relation of the table.
2. I would like to **have one User (maybe more)** in a **Group** that has the **permission** to do certain stuff **that normal User cant do**. Such as **Creating New Place, Deleting A Place**
3. How should I define my table structure?

Any thoughts please? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thank you

Comment: In order to let a user be in many Groups and that a Grup has many users you should introduce a new table for a many-to-many relation between Group and User in this thread you can see an example of a many to many relation [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have one more table in order to create what is known as a many to many relationship between the users and the groups.
Since you didn't specify the rdbms you are working with, I'll use SQL Server for my code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TblUserToGroup
(
    UserToGroup_UserId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TblUser(UserId),
    UserToGroup_GroupId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TblGroup(GroupId),
    UserToGroup_IsAdmin bit DEFAULT 0        
    CONSTRAINT UC_UserToGroup UNIQUE(UserToGroup_UserId, UserToGroup_GroupId)
)
```

As you can see, there is also an IsAdmin column that can take values of 0 or 1. If you only want one admin user for each team, you can add a check constraint to prevent having more then one admin for each group.