# Postgresql Iterate over an array field and use the records for another query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, many-to-many

I'm trying to iterate over an array field in order to use every record as
a parameter to query and finally join all results, but I need help to get it.

I have a table with an array field called `fleets` and it can have one or more values ie. `{1,2,3}` I need iterate over every value to get all vehicles belonging to these fleets.

With a subquery I'm getting 3 rows with these values `1`,`2`,`3`

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE fleet_fk=(
   SELECT unnest(fleets) FROM auth_user WHERE id=4)
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `fleets` is an array column you have a couple of options.

Either use the `ANY` construct directly (no need to [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)):

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles 
WHERE fleet_fk = ANY(SELECT fleets FROM auth_user WHERE id = 4);
```

Or rewrite as join:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   auth_user a
JOIN   vehicles  v ON v.fleet_fk = ANY(a.fleets)
WHERE  a.id = 4;
```

Or you can `unnest()`, then you don't need `ANY` any more:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   auth_user a
     , unnest(a.fleets) fleet_fk   -- implicit LATERAL join
JOIN   vehicles  v USING (fleet_fk)
WHERE  a.id = 4;
```

This is assuming you don't have another column named `fleet_fk` in `auth_user`. Use the more explicit `ON` clause for the join in this case to avoid the ambiguity.

Be aware that there are **two implementation** for `ANY`.

- [`ANY` for sets](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)
- [`ANY` for arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20214)

Behavior of the beasts is basically the same, you just feed them differently.

#### DB design

Consider normalizing the hidden many-to-many (or one-to-many?) relationship in your DB schema:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Answer (score 2):

If your query raises the `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` that means that you should use [`ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html):

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles 
WHERE fleet_fk = ANY(
   SELECT unnest(fleets) FROM auth_user WHERE id=4)
```