# Query to find projects without leader

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I'm doing a java application with a Postgres database and the following schema:

[image]

The entity `employee`, `rol`, `project` has some information inside,and the entity participants is empty. I want to show in my application a table of all projects with no leader assigned yet. I'm sure that#s possible with an SQL query but I'm not sure how. I tried this query:

```
SELECT p.projectnumber from participants pa, projecto p
where p.projectnumber=pa.projectnumber and pa.leaderid IS NULL;
```

But no rows are returned. That's because the participants entity is empty, but I cannot fill that entity with only the projectnumbers. Do you think I could make it easier with a query or well any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show on my application a table that shows all the projects with no Leader assigned yet

Guessing that leaders are signified by having a non-null value in `participants.leaderid`:

```
SELECT projectnumber
FROM   projecto p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   participants
   WHERE  projectnumber = p.projectnumber
   AND    leaderid IS NOT NULL
   );
```

You can solve it with a `LEFT JOIN` as well, but then include the `leaderid` in the join condition:

```
SELECT p.projectnumber
FROM   projecto p
LEFT   JOIN participants pa ON pa.projectnumber = p.projectnumber
                           AND pa.leaderid IS NOT NULL
WHERE  pa.projectnumber IS NULL;
```

The check on `leaderid` in the `WHERE` condition (*after* the `LEFT JOIN`) cannot distinguish whether the column `leaderid` is NULL in the underlying table or because there is no connected row in `participants` at all. In this particular query, the result would still be correct (no participant, no leader). But it would return one row per participant that's not a leader, and I expect you want to list every leader-less project once only. You would have to aggregate, but why join to multiple non-leaders to begin with?

Basics:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

That aside, your relational design doesn't seem to add up. What's to prevent multiple leaders for the same project? Why `varchar(30)` for most columns? Why no FK constraint between `participant` and `project`? Why `projecto` in the query, but `project` in the ER diagram? Etc.

Comment: well the problem i must design tells me that an employee can be in one or more projects, so i think he can be the leader of many projects. i will take in consideration all your questions, but i can only tell you i started learning the fundamentals of data bases, so i'm still a newbee on this matter.  I still have a long path to learn :D

Comment: @DanielEstebanLadinoTorres: One project can have many employees (as participants), one employee can take part in many projects. Seems like a typical many-to-many relationship. The role played can be considered an additional attribute (simplified). Instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860

Comment: also thanks for correcting the question, my native language is spanish so i migth have a few grammar errors >.<

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join assuming projects which don't have entries in Participants table will be without leader:

```
SELECT p.projectnumber 
FROM projecto p LEFT JOIN participants pa
ON p.projectnumber=pa.projectnumber 
WHERE pa.leaderid IS NULL;
```