# Create a foreign key from two different tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables in PostgreSQL:

```
create Table student (
 studentID integer primary key,
 studentname text
);

create Table courses (
 courseID text primary key,
 schoolname text
);
```

I want to create a third table `schoolstudent` that has a foreign key `(studentID, schoolname)` where `studentID` references the primary key of the `student` table and `schoolname` references the `schoolname` key in the `courses` table.

How can I create a foreign key from two different tables in PostgreSQL 9.4 or 9.5?

Answer (score 2):

A FK constraint requires a UNIQUE or PK constraint on the target column(s), which `schoolname` obviously cannot provide. You need another table with unique rows per school:

```
CREATE TABLE school(
  school_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  schoolname text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE student(
 student_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 studentname text
 );

CREATE TABLE schoolstudent(
 school_id  int REFERENCES school,
 student_id int REFERENCES student,
 PRIMARY KEY (school_id, student_id)
);

CREATE TABLE course(
 course_id text PRIMARY KEY,
 school_id int REFERENCES school
);
```

Using short syntax for foreign key constraints. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

If you really need `schoolname` in the `schoolstudent` table (I seriously doubt that, looks like a ***design error***), you *can* just add it. To enforce referential integrity you can *include* it in the foreign key, but you need a (redundant) matching `UNIQUE` constraint on `school(school_id, schoolname)`, too.

```
CREATE TABLE schoolstudent(
 school_id  int,
 student_id int REFERENCES student,
 schoolname text,
 PRIMARY KEY (school_id, student_id),
 CONSTRAINT schoolstudent_combo_fk FOREIGN KEY (school_id, schoolname)
    REFERENCES school (school_id, schoolname) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Using explicit syntax in this case. And I suggest to cascade updates.

**Or** if `schoolname` is actually guaranteed to be `UNIQUE` (again, my doubts) you can replace `school_id` completely and just use `schoolname` as PK and FK column. Long `text` columns are not very efficient for the purpose, though - if performance matters. And schoolnames change, which is not ideal for PK columns.

You still need a separate `school` table in any case.

Comment: Is their a way that I can use the schoolname without having to create new table or it is not possible? because i need the schoolname in the 'schoolstudent' table

Comment: @R.Y.H: Consider the addendum.

Comment: `is there a way that I can use the schoolname withou ...` This depends on whether `schoolname` is fully dependent on course_id (we don't know, you mabe do know). If the same course can be tought at *more than one* school, *at least* one extra table will be needed. (and studentcourse will have to refer to student+{course,school}

Answer (score 0):

you can set many to many relation only if both the fields are **Unique**(probably Primary Keys).if above condition is Fulfilled you can use

```
CREATE TABLE Schoolstudent(
   ID INT references     student(studentID),
   Schoolname CHAR(50)  references courses(Schoolname),

);
```

But `schoolname` in table `courses` should be **unique or PK**.

Comment: Is there any way that I can combine the studentID with the schoolname as a foreign key so it becomes unique. Since studentID is unique so the foreign key(studentID, schoolname) will become unique??                                                  For example, if we have coursename attribute, we can create foreign key(courseID, coursename) references  courses(courseID,coursename). Can we do the same thing if the two attributes are in different tables??