# Select rows with most similar set of attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a **PostgreSQL 8.3.4** DB to keep information about photo taggings.

**First off, my table definitions:**

```
create table photos (
   id integer
 , user_id integer
 , primary key (id, user_id)
); 

create table tags (
   photo_id integer
 , user_id integer
 , tag text
 , primary key (user_id, photo_id, tag)
);
```

**What I'm trying to do + simple example:**

I am trying to return all the photos that have at least *k* other photos with at least *j* common tags.

I. e., if Photo *X* has these tags (info field in the tags table):

```
gold 
clock
family
```

And photo *Y* has the next tags:

```
gold
sun 
family
flower
```

*X* and *Y* have 2 tags in common. For `k = 1` and `j = 2` *X* and *Y* will be returned.

**What I have tried**

```
    SELECT tags1.user_id , users.name, tags1.photo_id
    FROM users, tags tags1, tags tags2
    WHERE ((tags1.info = tags2.info) AND (tags1.photo_id != tags2.photo_id)
    AND (users.id = tags1.user_id))
    GROUP BY tags1.user_id, tags1.photo_id, tags2.user_id, tags2.photo_id, users.name
    HAVING ((count(tags1.info) = <j>) and (count(*) >= <k>))
    ORDER BY user_id asc, photo_id asc
```

**My *failed* results:**

When I tried to run it on those tables:

`photos`

```
photo_id       user_id
   0             0
   1             0
   2             0
   20            1
   23            1
   10            3
```

`tags`

```
photo_id     user_id       tag
   0           0            Car
   0           0            Bridge
   0           0            Sky
   20          1            Car
   20          1            Bridge
   10          3            Sky
```

The result for `k = 1` and `j = 1`:
*Expected:*

```
|   user_id    |  User Name   |   photo_id   |
| 0            | Bob          | 0            |
| 1            | Ben          | 20           |
| 3            | Lev          | 10           |
```

*Actual:*

```
|   user_id    |  User Name   |   photo_id   |
| 0            | Bob          | 0            |
| 3            | Lev          | 10           |
```

For `k = 2` and `j = 1`:
*Expected:*

```
|   user_id    |  User Name   |   photo_id   |
| 0            | Bob          | 0            |
```

*Actual:* empty result.

For `j = 2` and `k = 2`:
*Expected:* empty result.

*Actual:*

```
|   user_id    |  User Name   |   Photo ID   |
| 0            | Bob          | 0            |
| 1            | Ben          | 20           |
```

How to solve this properly?

Comment: For `k = 1, j = 1` your expected output contradicts your definition — for photos `0` and `20` has 2 common tags. The same for `k=2, j=2`. Perhaps you should revise your conditions.

Comment: Your table definition is not an actual table definition. A complete `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d tbl` in psql would be *much* more useful. And *always* your version of Postgres. And clarify table and column names, please. `photos` or `users`? `User ID ` or `user_id`? Ambiguity is not helping.

Comment: I have edited my question and now it meets the advised requirements

Comment: Are you serious about `PostgreSQL 8.3.4`?  [That's just too old and unsupported now.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Consider upgrading to a current version.

Comment: It's not up to me, do you have an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: I took the liberty to roll back your last edit, assuming you removed the essential table definitions by accident ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with your **current design**, this uses only basic SQL features and should work for Postgres 8.3, too (untested):

```
SELECT *
FROM   photos p
WHERE (
   SELECT count(*) >= 1  -- k other photos
   FROM  (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   tags t1
      JOIN   tags t2 USING (tag)
      WHERE  t1.photo_id =  p.id
      AND    t1.user_id  =  p.user_id
      AND   (t2.photo_id <> p.id OR
             t2.user_id  <> p.user_id)
      GROUP  BY t2.photo_id, t2.user_id
      HAVING count(*) >= 1  -- j common tags
      ) t1
   );
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT id, user_id
   FROM  (
      SELECT t1.photo_id AS id, t1.user_id
      FROM   tags t1
      JOIN   tags t2 USING (tag)
      WHERE (t2.photo_id <> t1.photo_id OR
             t2.user_id  <> t1.user_id)
      GROUP  BY t1.photo_id, t1.user_id, t2.photo_id, t2.user_id
      HAVING count(*) >= 1    -- j common tags
      ) sub1
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   HAVING count(*) >= 1  -- k other photos
   ) sub2
JOIN   photos p USING (id, user_id);
```

In Postgres 9.3 or later you could use a correlated subquery with a `LATERAL` join ...
The above are probably even faster than my first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT photo_id, user_id
   FROM   tags t
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   HAVING (
      SELECT count(*) >= 1
      FROM  (
         SELECT photo_id, user_id
         FROM   tags
         WHERE  tag = ANY(array_agg(t.tag))
         AND   (photo_id <> t.photo_id OR
                user_id  <> t.user_id)
         GROUP  BY 1, 2
         HAVING count(*) >= 2
         ) t1
      )
   ) t
JOIN photos p ON p.id = t.photo_id
             AND p.user_id = t.user_id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d5689/3) showing both on Postgres 9.3.

The 1st query just needs the right basic indexes.

For the 2nd, I would build a materialized view with integer arrays, install the [intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html) module, a GIN index on the integer array column for better performance ...
Related:

- [Order result by count of common array elements](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122511/3684)

### Proper design

It would be much more efficient to have a single column serial PK for `photos` and only store IDs of tags per photo ...:

```
CREATE TABLE  photo (
   photo_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , user_id  int NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE  tag (
   tag_id serial PRIMARY KEY 
 , tag    text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE  photo_tag (
   photo_id int REFERENCES (photo)
 , tag_id   int REFERENCES (tag)
 , PRIMARY KEY (photo_id, tag_id)
);
```

Would make the query much simpler and faster, too.

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: Thanks, a there an alternative to array_agg? My db doesn't support it. I tried changing it to select tag from tags but it gave me a wrong result for some reason

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer: I added a solution for pg 8.3 and some more advice.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer: Note the fixed bug: Since your update revealed a multicolumn PK, we need to group by all columns of the PK / FK: `GROUP  BY t2.photo_id, t2.user_id`. Plus, I added another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to calculate similarity between all photos of all users by common tags.

I think you need this:

```
SELECT 
    A.user_id,
    A.photo_id,
    B.user_id,
    B.photo_id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM 
                tags TA 
                JOIN tags TB ON TA.tag = TB.tag
            WHERE   
                A.user_id = TA.user_id
                AND A.photo_id = TA.photo_id
                AND B.user_id = TB.user_id
                AND B.photo_id = TB.photo_id
    ) AS common_tags
FROM
    users A
    ,users B
WHERE
    -- Exclude results to self
    A.user_id <> B.User_id
    AND A.photo_id <> B.photo_id
```

Comment: Where is the j,k part?