# Get substring from regular expression - everything up to a character

Tags: regex, postgresql, database-design, pattern-matching

There is a questions table with a column called `options` which contains

```
'r>>>>>5####answer1|4####answer2|3####answer3|2####answer4|1####answer5'
```

Which are pairs of possible answers

- 5 = answer1
- 4 = answer2
- etc.

The questions are set up by users but the pattern is the same.

Another table has a users answer which is the option selected. I'm attempting to write SQL to extract the answer text.

For example `4` should display `answer2`.

I tried:

```
SELECT substring(question.options from '%4####@"%@"[\|]%' for '@') AS answertext
FROM ...
```

But it displays `answer2|3####answer3|2####answer4`.

How do I get everything up to the first `|`?

Comment: `substring('r>>>>>5####answer1|4####answer2|3####answer3|2####answer4|1####answer5' from '4#+([^\|]+)')`

Comment: awesome!! thank you :)

Comment: Also try `select x[1] as n, x[2] as a from regexp_matches('r>>>>>5####answer1|4####answer2|3####answer3|2####answer4|1####answer5', '([\d]+)#+([^\|]+)', 'g') as t(x);` - probably it will be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression [supplied by @Abelisto in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131842/postgresql-substring-from-regular-expression-everything-up-to-a-character/38134066#comment63695115_38131842) works nicely. You don't need to escape `|` in the character class, so it can be:

```
SELECT substring(options, '4#+([^|]+)' ...
```

Assuming the number of the answer is limited to a *single* digit, there is a simple solution without regular expressions, too:

```
SELECT right(x, -5) AS answer
FROM   unnest( string_to_array(right(
         'r>>>>>5####answer1|4####answer2|3####answer3|2####answer4|1####answer5'
       , -6), '|')) x
WHERE  x LIKE '4%';  -- pick number
```

Applied to your table:

```
SELECT right(x, -5) AS answer
FROM   question q, unnest( string_to_array(right(q.options, -6), '|')) x
WHERE  q.question_id = 1
AND    x LIKE '4%';
```

---

But really, you should [***normalize***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your unfortunate design. It's a 1:n design between question and answers. Assuming a PK `question.question_id` you can fix it quickly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE answer AS
SELECT q.question_id, left(x,1)::int AS answer_id, right(x, -5) AS answer
FROM   question q, unnest(string_to_array(right(q.options, -6), '|')) x;

ALTER TABLE answer
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (question_id, answer_id)
 , ADD CONSTRAINT q_fk FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(question_id)
       ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE question DROP column options;
```

Then your query simply is:

```
SELECT answer
FROM   answer
WHERE  question_id = 1
AND    answer_id = 4;
```

Related:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)