# How to have a foreign key pointing to two primary keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm trying to simplify a database structure that includes two tables: `matches` and `team_statistics`:

[image: ER diagram]

The column `team_statistics.team_id` should be a foreign key that references *either* `matches.teams_id` *or* `matches.teams_id1`. Similarly, `team_statistics.group_id` should be a foreign key referencing *either* `matches.groups_id` *or* `matches.groups_id1`.
So each row in `team_statistics` should be for one single team.

How to do this in PostgreSQL?

If there are other ways of doing this by having another table between `matches` and `team_statistics`, I'm open for suggestion. But I would still like to know how to have one foreign key referencing two primary keys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Rules for FK constraints

To answer the question in the title and at the end of your text:

*"I would still like to know how to have one foreign key referencing two primary keys."*

That's impossible.

- A [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) constraint can only point to ***one*** table and each table can only have ***one*** [`PRIMARY KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) constraint.
- Or you can have *multiple* `FOREIGN KEY` constraints on the same column(s) referencing *one* `PRIMARY KEY` of a (different) table each. (Rarely useful.)

**However**, a single PK or FK *can* span multiple columns.
And a FK can reference any explicitly defined unique (set of) column(s) in the target, not just the PK. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.

A multicolumn PK or [`UNIQUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) constraint can only be referenced by a multicolumn FK constraint with matching column types.

### What you ask

Since it is not allowed to use the same column more than once in the column list of a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, the target list of a `FOREIGN KEY` can also not use the same column more than once. But there is nothing to keep us from using the same column more than once in the ***source*** list. Herein lies the potential to implement what you are asking (but probably did not mean to):

*"In the `team_statistics` table the `team_statistics.team_id` should be a foreign key that references `matches.team_id` and `matches.team_id1`"*

The combination of `(team_id, team_id1)` in table `matches` would need to be defined `UNIQUE`. Values in `team_statistics.team_id` would be restricted to cases with `team = team1` in table `matches` as logical consequence:

```
ALTER TABLE matches
ADD constraint matches_teams_groups_uni UNIQUE (team_id, team_id1);

ALTER TABLE team_statistics
  ADD constraint team_statistics_team_group fkey
  FOREIGN KEY (team_id, team_id)  -- same column twice!
  REFERENCES matches(team_id, team_id1);
```

Might even make sense for certain setups, but not yours.

### What you probably need

My educated guess is you want something like this:

*`(match_id, team_id)` in table `team_statistics` should be a foreign key that references **either** `(match_id, team_id)` **or** `(match_id, team_id1)` in table `matches`.*

And that's not possible with FK constraints and just two tables. You *could* abuse a `CHECK` constraint with a fake `IMMUTABLE` function and make it `NOT VALID`. See chapter "Cheaper with a CHECK constraint" in this answer:

- [How to avoid a cyclic dependency (circular reference) between 3 tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124019/3684)

But that's advanced trickery and less reliable. Not my suggestion here, so I am not going to elaborate. I suggest to **[normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)** your schema in a useful way, like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE team (team_id serial PRIMARY KEY
                 , team text NOT NULL UNIQUE);     -- add more attributes for team

CREATE TABLE match (match_id serial PRIMARY KEY);  -- add more attributes for match

CREATE TABLE match_team (
   match_id  int  REFERENCES match        -- short notation for FK
 , team_id   int  REFERENCES team
 , home boolean                           -- true for home, false for away team
 , innings_score int
 -- more attributes of your original "team_statistics"
 , PRIMARY KEY (match_id, team_id, home)  -- !!! (1st column = match_id)
 , UNIQUE (team_id, match_id)             -- optional, (1st column = team_id)
);
```

`home` marks the home team of the match but, by inclusion in the PK, also restricts to *max. two teams per match*. (PK columns are defined `NOT NULL` implicitly.)

The optional `UNIQUE` constraint on `(team_id, match_id)` prevents teams from playing against themselves. By using the inverted sequence of index columns (irrelevant for enforcing the rule) this also provides an index complementary to the PK, which is typically also useful. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

You *could* add a separate `match_team_statistics`, but that would just be an optional 1:1 extension to `match_team` now. Alternatively, just add columns to `match_team`.

I might add **views** for typical displays, like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW match_result AS
SELECT m.match_id
     , concat_ws(' : ', t1.team, t2.team) AS home_vs_away_team
     , concat_ws(' : ', mt1.innings_score, mt2.innings_score) AS result
FROM   match           m
LEFT   JOIN match_team mt1 ON mt1.match_id = m.match_id AND mt1.home
LEFT   JOIN team       t1  ON t1.team_id = mt1.team_id
LEFT   JOIN match_team mt2 ON mt2.match_id = m.match_id AND NOT mt2.home
LEFT   JOIN team       t2  ON t2.team_id = mt2.team_id;
```

Basic advice:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: Regardin your point: "Or you can have multiple FOREIGN KEY constraints on the same column(s) referencing one PRIMARY KEY of a (different) table each. (Rarely useful.)", when would it be useful since you say it's rarely so? This approach occurred to me as a way to solve a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to track teams to groups somewhere.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE team_groups (
    team_id int,
    group_id int,
    primary key (team_id, group_id)
);
```

then you need the matches table to have two foreign keys against this.  Then your statistics table should reference that as well.

You could aso create multiple foreign keys from team_statistics to matches but if you do this, you will run into an inability to grab statistics until a team is both on one side and the other side of a match.

Answer (score -1):

If I got your concept right, here is an example:

```
t=# create table matches(team_id int unique,team_id1 int unique);                             CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into matches values (0,0),(1,1),(2,3);                                             INSERT 0 3
t=# create table team_statistics (team_id int);                                               ERROR:  relation "team_statistics" already exists
t=# drop table team_statistics;
DROP TABLE
t=# drop table matches cascade;
DROP TABLE
t=# create table matches(team_id int unique,team_id1 int unique);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into matches values (0,0),(1,1),(2,3);
INSERT 0 3
t=# create table team_statistics (team_id int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# alter table team_statistics add constraint fk1 foreign key (team_id) references matches(team_id);
ALTER TABLE
t=# alter table team_statistics add constraint fk2 foreign key (team_id) references matches(team_id1);
ALTER TABLE
t=# insert into team_statistics values (0);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into team_statistics values (1);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into team_statistics values (2);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "team_statistics" violates foreign key constraint "fk2"
DETAIL:  Key (team_id)=(2) is not present in table "matches".
t=# insert into team_statistics values (3);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "team_statistics" violates foreign key constraint "fk1"
DETAIL:  Key (team_id)=(3) is not present in table "matches".
t=# select * from team_statistics;
 team_id
---------
       0
       1
(2 rows)

t=# select * from matches;
 team_id | team_id1
---------+----------
       0 |        0
       1 |        1
       2 |        3
(3 rows)
```