# One foreign key references multiple primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I have two tables with single primary key columns in each of those two tables and another table (table 3) which has a foreign key that refers both of those above primary key's columns.

Now I want to insert records into table 3 if it present in either of those two primary key tables.

**Note**: I don't want to create a new table that is combination of primary key tables and add reference to that newly created table

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: @ZaidMirza -  /*create table table1(id int primary key) * / /* create table table2(id int primary key) */ /*create table table3(id int foreign key references table1(id)) */ /*alter table table3 add constraint fk_id foreign key(id) references table2(id)*/......In This table 3 is refereing to both table1 and table2 .now i want to enter records in table3 if it has the same record in either table1 or table2. Is there any way to do it sql server

Comment: @ZaidMirza- in the above example mentioned it is allowing me to enter data into table3 if it is present in both the tables(table1 and table2)

Answer (score 2):

As **Erwin Brandstetter** stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285952/2118383)

### Rules for FK constraints

To answer the question in the title and at the end of your text:

*"I would still like to know how to have one foreign key referencing two primary keys."*

That's impossible.

- A [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) constraint can only point to ***one*** table and each table can only have ***one*** [`PRIMARY KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) constraint.
- Or you can have *multiple* `FOREIGN KEY` constraints on the same column(s) referencing *one* `PRIMARY KEY` of a (different) table each. (Rarely useful.)

**However**, a single PK or FK *can* span multiple columns.
And a FK can reference any explicitly defined unique (set of) column(s) in the target, not just the PK. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.

A multicolumn PK or [`UNIQUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) constraint can only be referenced by a multicolumn FK constraint with matching column types.

Basic advice:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into table3 (col1, col2 ...)
(select col1, col2 ... from table1
union
select col1, col2 ... from table2);
```

You can optionally put where clauses or split the SQL into 2, instead of a union.

This is standard ANSI SQL and should work on any DBMS