# Enforce relationship via a foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Let's say I have the following tables:

Questions, Choices, Answers

Each Question has many Choices (Choices has a `question_id` foreign key.)

The Answers table has two foreign keys, `question_id` and `choice_id`, and these constraints prevent answers that refer to a non-existent `question` or `choice`, but I want to prevent *invalid* choices, too.

How could I express a constraint (maybe that's not the right word) that only allows answers where the `choice_id` is a valid choice for the given `question_id`? For example, if I had 2 questions, each with 2 choices:

- Q1 (id = 1)

  - A (id = 1)
  - B (id = 2)
- Q2 (id = 2)

  - C (id = 3)
  - D (id = 4)

I want to allow answers like (`question_id` = 1, `choice_id` = 1 (or 2)) and prevent answers like (`question_id` = 1, `choice_id` = 4) because that's not a valid choice for the question.

Comment: I struggle to understand what the difference between a choice and an answer would be here. Is answer the choice a user picks for a question?

Comment: Yeah, maybe they could use better names, but the "answer" is the user's submission, and the "choices" are the valid options for a question (a multiple-choice one). Got any ideas for better names?

Comment: It looks to me like choices will have two different ways of identifying them,  the choiceId which will be unique across all choices of a ll questions,  and the Choice number the test taker sees,  which will be 1 through 5 for all of the questions.  You need to be careful not to confuse these two,  or else you will never get the foreign key constraints right.

Comment: @WalterMitty Indeed! I'll need to be careful of that. I'm storing an "order" property on a few tables to keep track of their index in each question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is a [FK constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) from `answer` to `choice` - the row in `choice` points to the *one* applicable question in return.

If you insist on having a column `answer.question_id` redundantly (there are corner cases where this makes sense) still only have a single, **multicolumn** FK constraint spanning both columns. This requires a matching multicolumn `UNIQUE` (or PK) constraint on table `choice` first (also typically redundant otherwise):

```
ALTER TABLE choice ADD CONSTRAINT choice_uni UNIQUE (question_id, choice_id);
```

Then:

```
ALTER TABLE answer ADD constraint answer_choice_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (question_id, choice_id)  REFERENCES choice(question_id, choice_id);
```

All involved columns are `NOT NULL` or you may have to do more: start by learning about the different match types of foreign key constraints in this case:

- [Differences between MATCH FULL, MATCH SIMPLE, and MATCH PARTIAL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71508/3684)

Related:

- [How to have a foreign key pointing to two primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268886/how-to-have-a-foreign-key-pointing-to-two-primary-keys/42285952#42285952)
- [Enforcing constraints “two tables away”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58972/3684)

Answer (score 3):

Why does your "answers" table have a `question_id`?

If it only has a `choice_id`, it will always refer to an existing choice. The choice itself links to a valid question, uniquely determining which question a given answer is for.

Comment: That's... a very good point :) Avoiding the problem entirely, I like it.

Comment: You don't even actually need an "answer" table at all. Only add a boolean "valid_answer" column to you `choices` table. Using a relation table here would be useful only if the large majority of questions doesn't have an answer at all, but only a few subset would.

Comment: @Obsidian "Answer" is not a relation table.

Comment: @Obsidian The use case here is for multiple users to be able to submit answers to multiple questions, where the "answers" table will have one row per response.

Comment: @Dave, I agree but you still don't need a dedicated "answer" table to do that. To be precise, this won't bring you more that a flag on questions in this case. In particular, this won't help you to restrict the content to at most one valid answer per question…

Comment: @Obsidian Your comments make no sense. I don't think you understand the data OP is trying to store.

Comment: @Obsidian There'll be many many more responses (answers) than there are choices or questions. The choices/questions are essentially static, or very rarely changing, but multiple users will take this survey so there'll be hundreds or thousands of answers.