# Counting with multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, relational-division

Assuming you have 3 tables: `posts`, `tags`, `post_tag`. There's an m:n relationship between the `posts` and `tags`, `post_tag` is used to connect them.

How would you count the number of posts that have a particular pair of tags? For instance, counting the number of posts that are tagged with both "news" and "featured"?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of **relational division**. There are many ways to solve it.
Assuming a [standard many-to-many implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225), this should be among the fastest and simplest:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   post_tag pt1
JOIN   post_tag pt2 USING (post_id)
WHERE  pt1.tag_id = (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'news')
AND    pt2.tag_id = (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag = 'featured');
```

That's counting posts with *at least* the two given tags. There can be more tags for the same post.

We have assembled an arsenal of techniques under this related question:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `EXISTS` for it

```
select count(*)
from posts
where exists(select 1 from post_tag 
             join tag on post_tag.tid = tag.tid
             where post_tag.pid = posts.pid and tag.name = 'news') and
      exists(select 1 from post_tag 
             join tag on post_tag.tid = tag.tid
             where post_tag.pid = posts.pid and tag.name = 'featured')
```