# How to define django's many to many field in postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django model called `Contexts` which is essentially a group that has a list of users.I have another model called `UserProperty` which has some user information.

```
class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProperty , related_name='context_users')

def getUserImagePath(instance,filename):
    return "/static/images/%s_%s"% (str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename)

class UserProperty(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=getUserImagePath, default="/static/images/user.png" ,null=True, blank=True)
    org = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

This works fine in my local system when I run a migration using `django manage.py`.But in the server for some reason, I cannot run migrations and I have to define the models manually in postgres (the server uses django _ postgres).So this is what I did

```
CREATE TABLE webhook_contexts(id integer, context_name character varying(100), context_description character varying(100), users text [], FOREIGN KEY (users) REFERENCES webhook_userproperty);
```

I am not sure exactly how to replicate this in postgres.For `users` field in `Contexts` model, I did `models.ManyToManyField(UserProperty , related_name='context_users')` so I assume the `users` must be an array in postgres that contains the fields of the referenced table `UserProperty` namely `username`, `pic`, `org`.So I do

```
.., users text [], FOREIGN KEY (users) REFERENCES webhook_userproperty)
```

But I get this error

```
ERROR:  there is no primary key for referenced table "webhook_userproperty"
```

But I did define an `id` for the webhook_userproperty which django treats as a primary key.Then why am I getting this error?Is my table definition wrong?

Comment: A many to many is not a specific field: it generates an *extra* table, a table with two foreign keys: one to the "origin" of the m2m, and one to the "target" of the m2m.

Comment: M2M fields are a separate table with two foreign keys. But rather than trying to do this manually, you would be better off diagnosing what is wrong with running migrations.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh I see.Can you show me how it might look like for my scenario?I am trying to follow this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql but I can't yet figure out how do I implement it in my case.

Comment: At the first look, it seems like a more of a django migrations problem. Just few question, do you have migrations files on production? E.g: did you ran python manage.py makemigrations followed by python manage.py migrate ? Can you paste  traceback you get running the command.

Comment: @VidyaSagar hey actually this server belongs to my company and there is some issue with running the migrations.So we are defining tables manually for the corresponding models for sometime now.

Comment: @SouvikRay: can you share the relevant migration files, and the (full) error you get when you run the migrations.