# How to store an array of users in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a django model which is basically a group called `Contexts`.It contains some fields like `name`, `description` and a user.Below is the model defined

```
class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    users = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

Currently there is only one user per `Context`.But I want to add more users to the same `Context`.So now I want to change the `users` field to an array field.By the way I am using django + postgres.

So this is what I do

```
class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    users = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.TextField()))
```

But then how do I append users to the `users` field?This is what I do normally to add a context

```
@csrf_exempt
def context_operation(request):
    user_request = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            if user_request.get("action") == "add":
                print("add")
                conv = Contexts.objects.create(
                    context_name=user_request.get("context_name"),
                    context_description=user_request.get("context_description"),
                    users=user_request.get("user")
                )

        except Exception as e:
            print("Context saving exception", e)
            return HttpResponse(0)
        return HttpResponse(1)
```

But how do I append one user at a time to the `users` field in the same context (assuming same context name is passed)?

Comment: Usually it is better *not* to store things as an array. First of all, not all databases *have* arrays, and furthermore, it usually will only create more trouble to do (efficient) querying. You usually store many-to-relations in a separate table. Django has support for this: a `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is better *not* to store things as an array. First of all, not all databases *have* arrays, and furthermore, it usually will only create more trouble to do (efficient) querying, especially if the elements in the array *refer* to other objects. You usually store many-to-relations in a separate table. Django has support for this: a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).

Furthermore the code probably already *has* a problem: you store `users` as a `CharField`. Now imagine that a user changes their username, then there is no longer a link here. If you want to refer to objects in (another) model, you should use relations, like a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, or `ManyToManyField`.

So we can probably rewrite it to:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    users = ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

The nice thing is, we no longer need to care about how Django represents this (efficiently), we can simply obtain all the `User`s of a `some_context` with `some_context.users.all()`. Those are then `User` objects (or other model objects if you later change the user model).

We can then add a `User` to an objects as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
def context_operation(request):
    user_request = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            if user_request.get("action") == "add":
                print("add")
                conv = Contexts.objects.create(
                    context_name=user_request.get("context_name"),
                    context_description=user_request.get("context_description"),
                )
                my_user = User.objects.get(username=user_request.get("user"))
                conv.users.add(my_user)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Context saving exception", e)
            return HttpResponse(0)
        return HttpResponse(1)
```

So we can fetch the user, and add it to the field. If you `user_request.get('user')` contains the *primary key* of the user, we can even omit fetching the `User` object, and use:

```
@csrf_exempt
def context_operation(request):
    user_request = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            if user_request.get("action") == "add":
                print("add")
                conv = Contexts.objects.create(
                    context_name=user_request.get("context_name"),
                    context_description=user_request.get("context_description"),
                )
                # if user_request.get('user') contains the *primary* key of the User model
                conv.users.add(user_request.get("user"))

        except Exception as e:
            print("Context saving exception", e)
            return HttpResponse(0)
        return HttpResponse(1)
```

Comment: hey this is great.But the problem is I can't run django migrations in the server for some reason.So I am using postgres in addition to django model.But I am having tough time to define the same `Contexts` model as a postgres table.I have asked a similar question in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810439/how-to-define-djangos-many-to-many-field-in-postgres?noredirect=1#comment90576223_51810439 but haven't got any success yet.It would be great if you could give some directions on this one. (Upvoting your answer)

Comment: by the way I have used django's User model.

Comment: "I can't run django migrations in the server" => then THIS is the real problem you should address instead of using a non standard non-normal "feature". If the reason you can't run migrations on the production server is that a db admin forbid it, then you want to get in touch with him to discuss the problem and find out how to do the required schema changes. I never met a db admin that would prefer denormalized data over a clean schema change, specially when the schema change only requires adding a m2m table, which is practically costless.

Comment: @SouvikRay: I think it is better to first try to fix the migration problem (effectively) than trying to "circumvent" the problem by using a different column type. Sure it might for now work, but it will cause a lot of problem later by not solving the "core issue".

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can do two ways either use the postgres json field or go with django ManyToManyField as below,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

# users field like below

users = JSONField()

or

users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```