# Finding all playlists that have a track with specific artist name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, postgresql-performance

I have two Postgres tables: `playlists` and `tracks`.

I've created `playlists_tracks` which is the many_to_many relationship between playlists and tracks.

Tracks contain multiple columns, but the one I'm looking at is `artist`.

What is the fastest way to query a list of all playlists that contain at least one track with an artist name containing, say, "The Beatles"? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest and simplest `DISTINCT` operation is .. not to multiply rows in the first place.
An [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join does that for your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   playlists p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT -- can be empty for EXISTS
   FROM   playlists_tracks pt
   JOIN   tracks t USING (track_id)
   WHERE  pt.playlist_id = p.playlist_id
   AND    t.artist = 'The Beatles'
   );
```

Assuming a typical many-to-many implementation like detailed here:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

(You could even nest `EXISTS` instead of the join in the subquery. Not sure if that helps more.)

If tables are big, **indexes** can help performance. Ideal for the particular query:

- `CREATE INDEX ON tracks (artist, track_id)`       -- columns in this order
- `CREATE INDEX ON playlists_tracks (track_id, playlist_id)`  -- columns in this order

Related:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Answer (score 0):

You must join the 3 tables and group by playlist like this:

```
select p.playlistid, p.name
from playlists p 
inner join playlists_tracks pt on pt.playlistid = p.playlistid
inner join (select * from tracks where artist = 'The Beatles') t on t.trackid = pt.trackid
group by p.playlistid, p.name
```

or using `distinct`:

```
select distinct p.*
from playlists p 
inner join playlists_tracks pt on pt.playlistid = p.playlistid
inner join tracks t on t.trackid = pt.trackid
where t.artist = 'The Beatles'
```