# SQL: Select only if multiple values are IN 1 column from CatalogTable

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I would really appreciate if you could help me with the following query; Having the following tables:

```
----------
**TableResults**
ResultId1
ResultId2
----------

---------------------
**TableResultsPatterns**
ResultId1  pattern1
ResultId1  pattern2
ResultId1  pattern4
ResultId2  pattern3
---------------------

---------------------
**TablePatterns**
pattern1 Name1
pattern2 Name2
pattern3 Name3
pattern4 Name4

---------------------
```

What is the best way to check if list of values (patternNames from User)
are IN or exist in the list of patterns of a particular Result

***For example select only the Results that have pattern Names(Name2, Name3)?***
I have something like:

```
SELECT***
JOINs***
WHERE***
and exists(select TablePatterns from TableResultsPatterns left join
    TablePatterns f on TableResultsPatterns.patternId = f.id
    where TableResultsPatterns.ResultsId = ResultIdX and patternName in ('Name2', 'Name4'))
GROUPBY***
***
```

*Edit 1:*

```
----------------
**TableResults**
(ResultId pk)
ResultId1
ResultId2
---------------

--------------------------------------------------------
**TableResultsPatterns**
(ResultId                    (fk TablePatterns.PatternId)
fk TableResults.ResultId)
ResultId1                     pattern1
ResultId1                     pattern2
ResultId1                     pattern4
ResultId2                     pattern3
--------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------
**TablePatterns**
(PatternId pk)  (PatternName)
pattern1         Name1
pattern2         Name2
pattern3         Name3
pattern4         Name4

------------------------------
```

in my main query i have:

```
right join TableResults wsr on wsr.patient_well_sample_id=XXX.id
left join TableResultsPatterns wsrfp on wsr.ResultId=wsrfp.ResultId
left join TablePatterns fp on wsrfp.final_patterns_id=fp.id
```

note: I´m  string_agg(the PAtternNAmes for every TableResult) in select

Comment: The "best way" depends on missing details and requirements: Postgres version, table definition showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statements), min, max, avg number of given patterns. Basically, "relational division" is the keyword here, and there are *many* possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of patterns and you want the results that contain them, you can use aggregation.  For instance:

```
select resultid
from resultpatterns rp
where pattern in (?, ?, ?)
group by resultid
having count(distinct pattern) = 3;  -- 3 is the size of the list
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, seems working! Still Testing it... I just had to left join your query to the TablePatterns to actually have patternName in (?, ?) and I will be counting and passing the number of patternNames the User  is filtering on, I´m assembling the query from Java

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division). 
For exactly two given "patterns" like in your example, and based on some assumptions, this should be *fastest*:

```
SELECT resultid
FROM   resultpatterns t1
JOIN   resultpatterns t2 USING (resultid)
WHERE  t1.pattern = (SELECT pattern FROM patterns WHERE name = 'Name2')
AND    t2.pattern = (SELECT pattern FROM patterns WHERE name = 'Name3')
```

Assumptions:

- You only need `resultid` in the `SELECT` list.
- You have have necessary indexes in place, so we don't descend into a sequential scan.
- You know the number of given patterns.
- A standard m:n implementation as outlined here:

  - [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
- `patterns.name` is defined `UNIQUE`.

The "best way" depends on missing requirements. There are *many* possible ways:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

Comment: Hi Erwin thanks for the answer, basically I want to know if a ResultId has all Given PatternNames, Indeed I get the ResultId as outer query column, table1->TableResults relates to table2-> TableResultsPatterns  (ResultId) and table2 has the PatternIds from table3 ->TablePatterns and the PatternNames that I need to used to filter on are in that 3rd table

Comment: @viruskimera: One way would be to resolve *names* to *patterns* with a subquery - as added above. Please address my requests if you wish to continue here. Any advice must be based on actual `CREATE TABLE` statements, indexes and requirements - and possibly more data.