# How to count missing rows in left table after right join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, left-join

There are two tables:

Table `education_data` (list of countries with values by year per measured indicator).

```
create table education_data 
(country_id int,
indicator_id int,
year date,
value float
);
```

Table `indicators` (list of all indicators):

```
create table indicators
(id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(200),
code varchar(25)
);
```

I want to find the indicators for which the highest number of countries lack information entirely
 i.e. max (count of missing indicators by  country)

I have solved the problem in excel (by counting blanks in a pivot table by country)

[pivot table with count for missing indicators by country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voc4E.png)

I haven't figured our yet the SQL query to return the same results.

I am able to return the number of missing indicators for a set country , read query below, but not for all countries.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM education_data AS edu
RIGHT JOIN indicators AS ind ON
edu.indicator_id = ind.id and country_id = 10 
WHERE value IS NULL 
GROUP BY country_id
```

I have tried with a cross join without success so far.

Comment: Do you have a table of countries?

Comment: @clamp yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to join on the `contries` as well, otherwise you can not tell if a contry has no entry in `education_data` at all:

```
create table countries(id serial primary key, name varchar);
create table indicators
(id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(200),
code varchar(25)
);
create table education_data 
(country_id int references countries,
indicator_id int references indicators,
year date,
value float
);

insert into countries values (1,'USA');
insert into countries values (2,'Norway');
insert into countries values (3,'France');
insert into indicators values (1,'foo','xxx');
insert into indicators values (2,'bar', 'yyy');
insert into education_data  values(1,1,'01-01-2020',1.1);

SELECT count (c.id), i.id, i.name
FROM countries c JOIN indicators i ON (true) LEFT JOIN education_data e ON(c.id = e.country_id AND i.id = e.indicator_id) 
WHERE indicator_id IS NULL
GROUP BY i.id;


count | id | name 
-------+----+------
     3 |  2 | bar
     2 |  1 | foo
(2 rows)
```

Comment: absoutely right. That's the right answer. If I wanted to add another condition:                    only countries with c.is_country field =True                                                                             how would I change the left outer join ?

Comment: You can add it to the `WHERE` clause or to the (first) `JOIN` condition.

Comment: I just wanted to double check.it thanks.  The question wasn't that difficult but my synapses are burned out.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the indicators for which the highest number of countries lack information entirely i.e. max (count of missing indicators by country)

That's a logical contradiction. The ...

> count of missing indicators by country

.. cannot be pinned on any specific indicators, since those countries don't *have* an indicator.

*The counts per country with "missing indicator" (i.e. `indicator_id IS NULL`)*:

```
SELECT country_id, count(*) AS ct_indicator_null
FROM   education_data
WHERE  indicator_id IS NULL
GROUP  BY country_id
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC;
```

Or, more generally, without valid indicator, which also includes rows where `indicator_id` has no match in table `indicators`:

```
SELECT country_id, count(*) AS ct_no_valid_indicator
FROM   education_data e 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM indicators i
   WHERE  i.id = e.indicator_id
   )
GROUP  BY country_id
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC;
```

`NOT EXISTS` is one of four basic techniques that apply here (`LEFT` / `RIGHT JOIN`, like you tried being another one). See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

You mentioned a `country` table. Countries without any indicator entries in `education_data` are not included in the result above. To find those, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM   country c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT
   FROM   education_data e
   JOIN   indicators     i ON i.id = e.indicator_id  -- INNER JOIN this time!
   WHERE  e.country_id = c.id
   );
```

Reports countries without valid indicator (none, or not valid).

---

**If** every country should have a valid indicator, after cleaning up existing data, consider:

- 1: adding an [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) to disallow invalid entries in `education_data.indicator_id`.
- 2: setting [`education_data.indicator_id NOT NULL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#id-1.5.4.6.6) to also disallow NULL entries.
  **Or** add a [`PRIMARY KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) on `(country_id, indicator_id)`, which makes both columns `NOT NULL` automatically.

.. which brings you closer to a valid **many-to-many** implementation. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and links.