# Creating a Hasura Relationship for Multiple Foreign Key Columns

Tags: hasura

I have two tables that represent a graph structure.

```
Location {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
}

Road {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  loc1Id: Int!
  loc2Id: Int!
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is have relationship that is an array of `Road` on `Location` that is made up of both `Road` that reference a `Location` via either the `loc1Id` or `loc2Id` fields/columns.

If I try to select both in the console in a single relationship create I get only the second selected one in the created relationship (and no error).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a many to many relationship.  The best way to create a many to many relationship is to have a join table.

```
location {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
}
Road {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
}
location_road {
  id: Int!
  road_id: Int!
  location_id: Int!
}
```

And create an array relationship between `road` and `location_road` and another array relationship between `location` and `location_road`

[How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql)

Comment: I'm trying to create a `2:*` relationship. If I use a join table then a Road could have more than 2 locations which isn't valid in my model.

Comment: @RoryHart - Although the console relationships tab shows only one selected relationship , the following query should work if you created the relationship manually by selecting both.


```query {
  location {
    name
    roads {
      location1 {
        id
        name
      }
      location2 {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this what you are expecting?