# Can one table reference another and have extra key values that are not in the referenced table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, ddl

I want to make a relationship between two tables.

I have a table A (`project`), with `project_id` as a primary key.
And a table B (`organization`). Projects can have many organizations.

The problem is that table B has values in `project_id` that are not in table A (but will be in upcoming tables).

Is there a way to allow the relationship even if there are non-existent keys? Or do I have to drop rows with violating values from table B?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. There is a projects table. And a project can have many organizations, but an organization can only belong to one project. An m:n relation. Yes? Then have a project ID in the organizations table. Are there organizations that don't belong to a project? Then make the project ID nullable. But what could it possible mean to have a project ID in the organizations table that does not exist in the project table? This doesn't seem to make sense. Please elaborate.

Comment: Seems that you are looking for some SQL trickery in order to deliberately introduce a *logical error* in the DB. Not a good idea. Step back and think it through.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of a [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) is to disallow rows in table B that would violate the constraint - and be sure of it.

That said, you can make use of the default **`MATCH SIMPLE`** behavior of **multicolumn FK constraints** for an elegant solution: FK is not enforced if at least one included column is `NULL`. See:

- [Differences between MATCH FULL, MATCH SIMPLE, and MATCH PARTIAL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71508/3684)

You need an additional column, the boolean flag `valid` in my demo:

```
CREATE TABLE project (
  project_id int NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, project text NOT NULL
, project_id_valid boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true  -- NOT NULL!
, PRIMARY KEY(project_id, project_id_valid)  -- !
, CONSTRAINT project_id_always_valid CHECK (project_id_valid)  -- only true
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN project.project_id_valid IS 'Redundant column to allow conditional multicolumn FK reference in table organization';

INSERT INTO project(project) VALUES ('project1');

CREATE TABLE organization (
  org_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, org text NOT NULL
, project_id integer NOT NULL
, project_id_valid boolean DEFAULT true  -- can be NULL!
, CONSTRAINT valid_project_fk FOREIGN KEY (project_id, project_id_valid) REFERENCES project -- !
, CONSTRAINT project_id_valid_or_null CHECK (project_id_valid)  -- only true
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN project.project_id_valid IS 'TRUE enforces the FK constraint valid_project_fk.';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e02c8c91bd98c0b9a638d4c05b303309)*

The model is simplified. Actual organizations would have multiple projects and you would use a many-to-many implementation. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

`CONSTRAINT project_id_always_valid CHECK (valid)` in combination with `NOT NULL` on the column enforces `project.project_id_valid` to always be `true`, which makes it a noise column. We need it for the multicolumn PK to allow our multicolumn FK constraint in `organization`. (Alternatively, use a plain PK on `(project_id)` and add a multicolumn `UNIQUE` constraint on `(project_id, project_id_valid)`.)

The corresponding column `organization.valid` can be `true` or `NULL`. If it's `true`, the FK constraint is enforced, else it's not. Effectively, you can switch the FK on or off per row. Exactly what you are after.

These are **standard SQL features**. Still, be sure to document the purpose of the trickery for the afterworld. I added comments on the column `project_id_valid` in this spirit.

Comment: Erwin, please don't provide answers to such vague and under-specified questions. Your answer is almost completely guesswork. The OP must tell us their full schema, including what are declared as Keys and Foreign Keys. Having a `project-Id` in table `B` that is sometimes a Foreign Key, and sometimes a dangling pointer smells to me like terrible schema design. Introducing a nullable column (especially a key) smells worse. As per @Thorsten's comment, the OP should explain what is the business requirement here.

Comment: @AntC Sure, [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) always helps to clarify. But this question is clear to me as it is. You seem to dislike nullable FK columns. OK, tell the world. I disagree. Postgres disagrees. The SQL standard disagrees. The default `MATCH SIMPLE` behavior of FK constraints is implemented proof of this. I even lead with the basics and a link to documentation. There is nothing misleading here. Nothing to justify a comment telling me not to answer.