# How to make sure result pairs are unique - without using distinct?

Tags: sql, distinct

I have three tables I want to iterate over. The tables are pretty big so I will show a small snippet of the tables. First table is **Students**:

| id | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | New York |
| 2 | Rebeka Jens | Miami |
| 3 | Amira Sarty | Boston |

Second one is **TakingCourse**. This is the course the students are taking, so `student_id` is the id of the one in Students.

| id | student_id | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 1 | 26 |
| 19 | 2 | 27 |
| 18 | 3 | 28 |

Last table is **Courses**. The id is the same as the `course_id` in the previous table. These are the courses the students are following and looks like this:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | History |
| 27 | Maths |
| 28 | Science |

I want to return a table with the location (address) and the type of courses that are taken there. So the results table should look like this:

| address | type |
| --- | --- |

The pairs should be unique, and that is what's going wrong. I tried this:

```
select S.address, C.type
from   Students S, Courses C, TakingCourse TC
    where TC.course_id = C.id 
    and S.id = TC.student_id
```

And this does work, but the pairs are not all unique. I tried `select distinct` and it's still the same.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: a student from New York can take a course in History and another student from Miami too can take up the same course, isnt it?. Distinct address,Type will therefore will unique

Comment: Please learn 'modern' `join` syntax. It's the standard for 30-odd years, it is much easier to read, much easier to write, and much easier to maintain.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Yes both students can take up the same course. But when 2 people from Miami choose history, the results are (Miami, history) and (Miami, history). Only an overview is needed, so that's why I don''t want duplicates

Comment: that is why on using distinct address,type you get a unique pair

Comment: If you use `SELECT DISTINCT S.address, C.type ...`, you shouldn't get duplicate results for `(Miami, history)`. Maybe there's trailing spaces or case-sensitive issues as play here.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple students can (and will) reside at the same address. So don't expect unique results from this query.

> Only an overview is needed, so that's why I don''t want duplicates

So fold duplicates. Simple way with `DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT s.address, c.type
FROM   students s
JOIN   takingcourse t ON s.id = t.student_id
JOIN   courses c ON t.course_id = c.id;
```

Or to avoid `DISTINCT` (why would you for this task?) and, optionally, get counts, too:

```sql
SELECT c.type, s.address, count(*) AS ct
FROM   students s
JOIN   takingcourse t ON s.id = t.student_id
JOIN   courses c ON t.course_id = c.id
GROUP  BY c.type, s.address
ORDER  BY c.type, s.address;
```

A missing `UNIQUE` constraint on `takingcourse(student_id, course_id)`  could be an *additional* source of duplicates. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)