# Find movies connected to all given tags

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I don't know how to phrase my SQL question so I will type out an expected scenario.

| MovieID | TagID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |

I want to select movieIds that have tag relationship with at least ALL these tags `[1,3,5]`.
So the expected output would be `1,3`.

Answer (score 5):

You can aggregate the tagids into an array and use the contains operator:

```
select movieid
from the_table
where tagid in (1,3,5)
group by movieid
having array_agg(tagid) @> array[1,3,5]
```

Comment: The `where` clause is logically redundant. Maybe good to boost speed.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm: logically, yes. But it improves performance because it avoids aggregating all rows.

Comment: I was just editing my comment to say so :)

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I need to be able to find tags that are a union of the where tags and intersections of the @> array clause

Answer (score 2):

A classical case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division).

Here is an arsenal of query techniques:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

The best solution depends on the complete situation. Postgres version, table size, cardinalities, indexes, performance requirements, result columns, ...

Typically among the fastest options:

```sql
SELECT movie_id
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (movie_id)
JOIN   tbl t3 USING (movie_id)
WHERE  t1.tag_id = 1
AND    t2.tag_id = 3
AND    t3.tag_id = 5;
```

Needs an **index** on `(tag_id)`, or better yet on `(tag_id, movie_id)` to be fast.

If `tbl` implements a many-to-many relationship - see:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Then there should be a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on these two columns. The query at hand prefers `(tag_id, movie_id)` over `(movie_id, tag_id)`. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

If column statistics are up to date (see `autovacuum`, `ANALYZE`), chances are that Postgres will start with the most selective tag to eliminate non-qualifying movies early.

Comment: thanks for the links. i am unable to google my problem because i dont even know what topic the query is about

Comment: *among the fastest options* I highly doubt that multiple self joins can be considered a fast option. Any of the other 2 solutions would perform better. Also, this scales terribly for more than 3 values.

Comment: @forpas: Run some tests (like I did many times) and feel free to correct your incorrect claims. Maybe some of this applies to other RDBMS that you are more accustomed to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure a_horse_with_no_name's answer works, and it's very clean.

Here's an approach that uses more vanilla sql.

```
WITH  vals (search_value) AS (VALUES (1),(3),(5)) 
    SELECT id
      FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                   mv.id,
                   mv.TagID
              FROM movie mv
             INNER
              JOIN vals v
                ON mv.tagID = v.search_value
           )
     GROUP
        BY id
    HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vals)
```

Edit: Just to call it out, since this type of question comes up for me every so often where instead of have a defined list of values I'm interested in the set of values from a column in another table. This approach can be used in that case without having to hardcode anything.

Comment: Well, the solution of @a_horse_with_no_name can be modified & reused without having to hardcode anything too. The array literal is to be replaced with a simple array-valued scalar subquery.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Good point, truth be told I'm not much of a Postgres guy and didn't know those functions.

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification to the query from @a_horse_with_no_name you can avoid double entering the target tags. Use a CTE to define the array then `unnest` forming the `in` clause. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d35f8b32a4b25c8db7f182b7543953cc))

```
with tag_list (tags) as 
     (select  array [tag1,tag2,tag3,...]) 
select distinct on (mt.movie_id) movie_id::integer  
  from <table_name> mt
 where mt.tag_id in ( select unnest(tags) from tag_list) 
 group by mt.movie_id 
having array_agg(tag_id) @> (select tags from tag_list);
```

If running often you can wrap it in a SQL function thus essentially building a parameterized query:

```
create or replace 
function get_movies_with_all_tags( tags_in integer[]) 
  returns table (movie_id integer)
 language sql 
as $$
    select mt.movie_id 
      from <table_name> mt
     where mt.tag_id in ( select unnest(tags_in)) 
     group by mt.movie_id 
    having array_agg(tag_id) @> tags_in
     order by mt.movie_id;     
$$;
```