# Implement FK constraints as depicted in ER-diagram

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

[image: ER diagram]

While making a table, I got  stuck at 2 things. We have 2 primary keys named "ID" in both `Patient` and `Employee`. And both of them are foreign keys to entity `Doctor`. How do I put this in `Doctor` table, I can't have 2 columns of the same name "ID" referencing different tables?

The second thing is Employee is related to itself as well, so how should I even think about this?

Comment: Where in the diagram does it imply that a `Patient.ID` is an FK to `Doctor.ID`?

Comment: "Make the CREATE TABLE statements in PSQL ..." makes no sense. psql is the interactive terminal, the RDBMS is PostgreSQL, or Postgres for short, never "psql".

Comment: @Dai That is not what I meant, I meant that ID is PK in both Patient and Employee. And both patient and employee have a relation to Doctor. And in order to satisfy this relation the primary keys of Patient and Employee need to be a FK in Doctors and these 2 PK are ID, the same thing which means I can use it to refer to different tables.

Comment: _"And in order to satisfy this relation the primary keys of Patient and Employee need to be a FK in Doctors"_ - no, that's incorrect: the diagram says you need `CREATE TABLE Treating( DoctorId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Doctors ( ID ), PatientId NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Patients ( ID ), PRIMARY KEY ( DoctorId, PatientId ) )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source and target column *name(s)* of a [FK constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) do not have to match.
But, quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> Of course, the number and type of the constrained columns need to match the number and type of the referenced columns.

That said, I am not a fan of the wide-spread anti-pattern that uses the generic name "id" for a surrogate PK column. Make it more descriptive, like `patient_id` for the table `patient`. Then FK columns can mostly share the same name, making everything clearer and queries on multiple connected tables simpler.

What's more, there is a many-to-many relationship between `doctor` and `patient`, which is typically implemented as *separate* relation. Something like `doctor_patient`. The FK columns would be added to that table. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

As to your 2nd question, the same table can be source *and* target for the same FK constraint, even the same column (for hierarchical structures), no problem.

Comment: what about the works at relation, it seems to have an attribute too, how do you express that in a table? Same goes for Employee when it has a relation thru mentor?

Comment: @User: `works_at` is just another m:n relationship like `doctor_patient` with an additional attribute `start_date` (implemented as column). My linked answer applies. "Mentor", OTH, materializes as self-referencing FK constraint.