# Postgres (Supabase) data structure question

Tags: arrays, postgresql, structure, supabase

I have a question on data table structure for Postgres (Supabase).

My users can create a profile, this is one table (users profile table). This has a foreign key linking ID to uuid in the built in auth table.

When creating a profile, they select a country (country table). Once selected, it will come up with a list of cities (cities table). The cities table has a column called country which has a foreign key linked to the country table to filter the cities list.

The users profile table has a country and city column with a foreign key linked to the relevant table.

This part all works fine.

What I need is users to be able to select multiple countries and cities, but I can't have the country and city columns as an array and linked to a foreign key in the other table.

Thoughts on how I can structure this?

Comment: Use a join table

Comment: [Ain't no such thing as "Postgre".](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi how would I structure the join table? Does it have foreign key links?

Comment: @Daryl Yes, it would have a user id column referencing the profile, and a city id column referencing the city. Both columns together form the primary key.

Comment: @Daryl You might have a second join table between profiles and countries, or have country id + city id columns in the first join table instead of only the city id, and make the city id nullable, depending on whether you want to allow selecting only a country without a city (and store that) or not.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the information. Would the profile then have a city id column that's an array of the join table city id column?

Comment: @Daryl No, the relationships between profiles and cities is stores in a single location, the junction table. If you need the array for anything, you can still query it with a subquery (`SELECT profile.*, ARRAY(SELECT city_id FROM profile_city WHERE profile_id = profile.id) AS cities FROM profile`)

Comment: The type of relationship you are looking for is called many-to-many relationships. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql