# How to JOIN a JSONB column with an array by a text column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

Using PostgreSQL 9.6+

Two tables (simplified to only the columns that matter with example data):

Table 1:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
key (PK) [Text]| resources [JSONB]
-------------------------------------------------------
asdfaewdfas    | [i0c1d1233s49f3fce, z0k1d9921s49f3glk]
```

Table 2:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
resource (PK) [Text]| data [JSONB]
-------------------------------------------------------
i0c1d1233s49f3fce   | {large json of data}
z0k1d9921s49f3glk   | {large json of data}
```

Trying to access the `data` column(s) of Table 2 from the `resources` column of Table 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unnest the JSON array and join to the second table. Like:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.data -- or just the bits you need
FROM   table1 t1, jsonb_array_elements_text(t1.resources) r(resource)
JOIN   table2 t2 USING (resource)
WHERE  t1.key = ?
```

Or, to preserve all rows in `table1` with empty / null / unmatched resources:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.data -- or just the bits you need
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(t1.resources) r(resource) ON true
LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 USING (resource)
WHERE  t1.key = ?
```

About `jsonb_array_elements_text()`:

- [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

There is an implicit `LATERAL` join in the first query. See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Consider a normalized DB design with a junction table with one row per linked resource instead of the column `table1.resources`, implementing the m:n relation properly. This way you can enforce referential integrity, data integrity etc. with relational features. And queries become simpler. `jsonb` for everything is simple *at first*. But if you work a lot with nested data, this may turn around on you.

- [Can PostgreSQL array be optimized for join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156345/can-postgresql-array-be-optimized-for-join/38160897#38160897)
- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013)

Comment: Hitting a ERROR:  column "resource" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table.

Comment: @ThomasChen: Forgot that the column name defaults to `value` for the function `jsonb_array_elements_text()`. Added a column alias and it should work now.

Comment: Followup: Having an edge case issue where if resources is empty [] then the join does not include that row from table 1. Is there a way to include table 1 rows with empty resources and join them to a blank row of table 2 on top of what it's doing now?

Comment: @ThomasChen. There is. `LEFT JOIN .. ON true`. Follow the first link in my answer for a detailed assessment. [The included fiddle should give a quick overview](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=588a9cba87833e8969e35a988f4cbb4f). I added a variant above to illustrate.